# Table cell with background color turning white when fadeTo called in FireFox 11

Tags: jquery, html-table

I have a large table which has a background-color on each td. I also have the following code:

```
    $('.table-cell').live('mouseover', function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('slow', 0.7);
    });


    $('.table-cell').live('mouseout', function () {
        $(this).stop().fadeTo('fast', 1.0);
    });
```

The mouseover is working fine.  The color will change to a lower opacity nicely but when your mouse leaves the cell the cell goes white (except for the text which continues to have a colored background).  After the fade completes the color will return properly but it looks really bad while it's changing.

We have this problem in FireFox 11 and IE8 (7 & 9 work fine).

Comment: it looks fine here, can you provide an example?  http://jsfiddle.net/cKWcv/

Comment: Your example has the same problem in FireFox 11 on my machine which I forgot to mention in my example.. shoot.. sorry about that! Fixed it

Comment: Ya that makes a difference.  Use the jquery UI color animation, works great in FF 11.  http://jqueryui.com/demos/animate/

Comment: Animate with opacity has the same problem.  Is opacity just not supported in FF?

Comment: it seems it's a bug in FF with `TD` and opacity (even not animated). I've tried this simple code, and that bug still appear: `$('td').hover(function () {
        $(this).css({'opacity': '0.7'});
    }, function () {
        $(this).css({'opacity': '1.0'});
    });`

Comment: Yes it seems to be a td issue, fadeto works great in FF http://api.jquery.com/fadeTo/

Comment: So how does one handle this?  There doesn't appear to be any feature detection we can use to disable the fading effects for Firefox and browser detection seems to be heavily recommended against.  Is this just one of those times where you have to do it?

Comment: If you uncheck normalize css in user1289347's fiddle it seems fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is `border-collapse: collapse;` this will solve the problem

```
table
{
    border-collapse:separate;
}
```

[**Example**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKWcv/5/)

In the comments I noticed that [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKWcv/) is not working like `Chrome` in `FF` because the `Normalized CSS` was checked and [**this fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/cKWcv/6/) just works fine in both `Chrome` and `FF` without `Normalized CSS`. Check [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-different-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css) to understand `Normalized CSS` that uses `border-collapse: collapse;`.

[**Nnormalize.css link**](https://raw.github.com/necolas/normalize.css/master/normalize.css)