# What is a user agent stylesheet?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I'm working on a web page in Google Chrome. It displays correctly with the following styles.

```
table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
}
```

It is important to note that I didn't define these styles. In Chrome developer tools, it says **user agent stylesheet** in place of the CSS file name.

Now if I submit a form and some validation error occurs, I get the following stylesheet:

```
table {
    white-space: normal;
    line-height: normal;
    font-weight: normal;
    font-size: medium;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-style: normal;
    color: -webkit-text;
    text-align: -webkit-auto;
}

table {
    display: table;
    border-collapse: separate;
    border-spacing: 2px;
    border-color: gray;
}
```

The `font-size` from these new styles is disturbing my design. Is there a way to force my stylesheets and if possible, completely overwrite Chrome's default stylesheet?

Comment: [chrome : how to turn off user agent stylesheet settings?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006356)

Comment: Note also that on Chrome (51) you get only those two table entries when you don't have a doctype declaration. Otherwise, you only get the second one.

Comment: Clear the chrome cache in more tools -> Clear browsing data

Comment: Related post [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18252356/465053). Understanding how user-agent (or browser) style sheet is different from user and author style sheets will help conceptualize things easily.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Answering the question in title, what is the user agent stylesheet, the set of default styles in the browser: Here are some of them:

- Chromium (Chrome): https://chromium.googlesource.com/chromium/src/third_party/+/master/blink/renderer/core/html/resources/html.css
- WebKit (Safari): https://github.com/WebKit/WebKit/blob/main/Source/WebCore/css/html.css
- Gecko (Firefox): https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/layout/style/res/html.css
- Serenity: https://github.com/SerenityOS/serenity/blob/master/Userland/Libraries/LibWeb/CSS/Default.css
- Mozilla Servo: https://github.com/servo/servo/blob/master/resources/user-agent.css

Personal opinion: Don't fight with them. They have good default values, for example, in rtl/bidi cases and are consistent nowadays. Reset what you see irrelevant to you, not all of them at once.

Comment: Accepting this answer, 10+ years after asking the question for the sake of future visitors.
I suddenly came across this question I asked 10+ years ago. I no longer have that doubt but this seems the correct answer to the original question. Accepting it so that it came at the top.

Answer (score 298):

What are the target browsers? Different browsers set different default CSS rules. Try including a CSS reset, such as the [meyerweb CSS reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/), to remove those defaults. Google "CSS reset vs normalize" to see the differences.

Comment: Thanks Oli. Is there any side-effect of removing browser's default CSS? I guess it is not recommended, is it? I need to decide between your ans (reset) or @BenM answer override with our own style. Any idea which is recommended approach?

Comment: I always reset/normalise my CSS before every project, that way you have an "almost" level field across browsers. I have never heard of a negative "side-affect" as such, I'm sure if you have a quick look on Google you will find that it is recommended.

Comment: Resetting styles can cause weird results with form fields, particularly around field borders or multi-part elements like type="file".

Comment: Even though reset/normalize might help, it doesn't really answer the question, of why the user agent stylesheet is changing? I have the same problem where on they UA styles become different for pre-rendered pages I use for SEO. Any ideas on why it changes?

Comment: See what Chrome sets by default to the webpage: http://trac.webkit.org/browser/trunk/Source/WebCore/css/html.css

Comment: Although this info is helpful, it doesn't really answer the question "What is a user agent stylesheet?"

Comment: For those wondering about a reset vs. normalize, this question has some good answers: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css

Answer (score 198):

If `<!DOCTYPE>` is missing in your HTML content you may experience that the browser gives preference to the "user agent stylesheet" over your custom stylesheet. Adding the doctype fixes this.

Comment: That's a great hint. You saved me some time of research. Worth noted that in my case I had that doctype declaration but I had a script before. It looks like the DOCTYPE must happen first thing in the page to enter into consideration.

Comment: Adding <!DOCTYPE> solved a very weird tr/td vertical alignment problem I had. Thanks for this answer.

Comment: This is nitpicking, but <!DOCTYPE html> fixed the problem for me.

Comment: I had <!DOCTYPE html> enabled but still had to normalise.

Comment: A detail that cost me several minutes to figure out: <doctype> must be at the very top. If there is an error message first, it fails. (Happened to me with Joomla maximum error messages)

Comment: This answer is just not true. Quirks mode doesn’t change how user agent styles are applied, and whether it’ll take some of those styles in preference to your styles; it just alters the base stylesheet that is used. (It does a very few other things differently, but not much; refer to [the spec](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/) for the substantial details.)

Comment: @ChrisMorgan quoting from the specification to which you have linked: "DOCTYPEs are required for legacy reasons. When omitted, browsers tend to use a different rendering mode that is incompatible with some specifications. Including the DOCTYPE in a document ensures that the browser makes a best-effort attempt at following the relevant specifications". In an ideal world DOCTYPE wouldn't be necessary. But to claim the answer is "just not true" is quite bold IMHO, especially considering the number of upvotes.

Comment: My code had the same symptoms as the OP's and the comment by @Sebas above put me on the right track - in my case, when my 4yo daughter had bashed the keyboard while I worked she inadvertently added a stray letter at the very start of line 1 of my file and I didn't notice... (facepalm) Cue an hour of unsuccessful troubleshooting before I finally spotted the error after investigating if there was anything entered before the <!DOCTYPE html> line... Thanks.

Comment: @Stiv This will go into history as (among other things of course) the period where people all over the world tried to work while taking care of their quarantined kids.

Comment: Brilliant!  Today my website suddenly displayed all tables too small.  Yesterday it was fine.  Googling “user agent stylesheet” brought me straight here.  And <!DOCTYPE> was the answer.  An “innocent” change that I had made had accidentally prepended a line of HTML before the <!DOCTYPE>.

Comment: This is the exact answer!

Comment: This answer made check the DOCTYPE at the top of my page, whereupon I found some garbage characters at the very start of the page which shouldn't have been there. Thanks.

Answer (score 138):

Regarding the concept “user agent style sheet”, consult section [Cascade](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/cascade.html#cascade) in the CSS 2.1 spec.

User agent style sheets are overridden by anything that you set in your own style sheet. They are just the rock bottom: in the absence of any style sheets provided by the page or by the user, the browser still has to render the content *somehow*, and the user agent style sheet just describes this.

So if you think you have a problem with a user agent style sheet, then you really have a problem with your markup, or your style sheet, or both (about which you wrote nothing).

Comment: @givanse, no, you see user agent style sheet effects when you don’t override them, and your sample markup is no exception. It will be parsed as one `li` element containing two `ul` elements with just text content; they are styled by user agent style sheet, but this styling can be overridden. (Whether the markup is invalid depends on context and on HTML version; but this does not affect styling.)

Comment: @givanse, that problem is not relevant to the question “what is a user style sheet”. If you think the problem is important, post it as a new question, with sufficient details. But the bullet in your jsfiddle is simple a bullet for the `li` element, and your style sheet does not override it.

Comment: In my situation, there was a CSS specifier problem, but this information about the User Agent was also helpful.

Answer (score 57):

Marking the document as HTML5 by the proper doctype on the first line, solved my issue.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>...
```

Comment: Can you please explain how exactly it is supposed to work? How HTML 5 is associated with undefined styles? I'll confirm but do you have any ready fiddle to confirm it?

Answer (score 49):

A user agent style sheet is a ”default style sheet” provided by the browser (e.g., Chrome, Firefox, Edge, etc.) in order to present the page in a way that satisfies ”general presentation expectations.” For example, a default style sheet would provide base styles for things like font size, borders, and spacing between elements.

It is also common to use a [CSS Reset](https://css-tricks.com/reboot-resets-reasoning/) to normalize or remove inconsistencies between browsers due to differences between which base styles are applied by each browser.

From the specification...

> A user agent's default style sheet should present the elements of the document language in ways that satisfy general presentation expectations for the document language. ~ [The Cascade](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html).

For more information about user agents in general, see *[user agent](https://www.w3.org/TR/UAAG20/#def-user-agent)*.

Answer (score 17):

Define the values that you don't want to be used from Chrome's user agent style in your own CSS content.

Answer (score 4):

Some browsers use their own way to read .css files.
So the right way to beat this:
If you type the command line directly in the .html source code, this beats the .css file, in that way, you told the browser directly what to do and the browser is at position not to read the commands from the .css file.
Remember that the commands writen in the .html file is stronger than the command in the .css.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem as one of my <div>'s had the margin set by the browser. It was quite annoying but then I figured out as most of the people said, it's a markup error.

I went back and checked my <head> section and my CSS link was like below:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="ex.css">`

I included `type` in it and made it like below:

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="ex.css">`

My problem was solved.

Answer (score 2):

I just wanted to expand on the response from @BenM based on what I [read here](https://bitsofco.de/a-look-at-css-resets-in-2018/) from Ire Aderinokun. Because the user-agent stylesheet provides helpful default styling, think twice before overriding it.

I had a dumb error where a button element didn't look right in Chrome. I had partially styled it because I didn't want it to look like a traditional button. However, I left out style elements like border, border-color, etc. So Chrome was stepping in to supply the parts that it thought I was missing.

The problem went away once I added styles like `border: none`, etc.

So if anyone else is having this problem, make sure you are explicitly overriding all the applicable default user-agent styles for an element if you notice it looks wonky, especially if you don't want to reset the user agent styles completely. It worked for me.

Comment: Shouldn't this be a comment instead of an answer?

Comment: @PeterMortensen yes, but I can't leave comments - not enough reputation.

Comment: Maybe it should be a comment... But, this solved an issue I have struggled with for couple of hours.

Answer (score 0):

Each browser provides a default stylesheet, called the user agent stylesheet, in case an HTML file does not specify one. Styles that you specify override the defaults.

Because you have not specified values for the table element’s box, the default styles have been applied.

Answer (score 0):

I found a case where user agent css was overriding my built-in or defined CSS and it turned out I was using "local overrides" feature in Chrome by accident on that page.

As such, of course only the user agent css was showing because the override was not allowing me to make changes.

Answer (score -1):

I ran into this same issue, it was because I was working with non-semantic html

```
<!--incorrect-->
<ul class="my-custom-font">
  <button>
    <a>user agent styles applied instead of my-custom-font</a>
  <button>
</ul>

<!--correct-->
<ul class="my-custom-font">
  <li>
    <a>now inherits from from my-custom-font</a>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Once the HTML was updated, styles were applied correctly

Answer (score -1):

- Every browser will have a rendering engine responsible for converting HTML document to web page.
- The rendering engine will have a stylesheet of its own for all the HTML elements, a kind of default stylesheet for all the HTML elements and this stylesheet is called user agent stylesheet.
- The rules of user agent stylesheet can be overwritten by author stylesheet.
- The rendering engine for google chrome browser is called . And if you look through its source code you will be able to find the default stylesheet.

check this https://www.linkedin.com/posts/smruti-sagar-pattanaik-a3a000195_html-css-chrome-activity-7027888128115847168-USil?utm_source=share&utm_medium=member_desktop

Comment: The question is why this stylesheet is somehow more important than my css rule applied by a class, but without `!important` mark :)

Answer (score -1):

User-agents, or browsers, have basic style sheets that give default styles to any document. These style sheets are named user-agent stylesheets. Most browsers use actual stylesheets for this purpose while others simulate them in code. The end result is the same.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. If a question already has answers, you need to make sure your answer is adding something meaningfully new and different than the existing answers. This answer does not provide anything meaningfully new and different than the 16 other answers to this question.

Answer (score -5):

I have a solution. Check this:

Error

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="text/css" type="stylesheet">
```

Correct

```
<link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
```

Comment: Please edit to explain how this works and why it helps.

Answer (score -7):

Put the following code in your CSS file:

```
table {
    font-size: inherit;
}
```

Comment: This does not really add anything new to this post. There is already an accepted answer, as well as 5 other answers, so please don't post late answers.