# Styling DataGrid GWT

Tags: css, gwt, datagrid

I am using vanilla GWT DataGrid `(com.google.gwt.user.cellview.client.DataGrid)` to construct a table. To play with the CSS styles I am using a similar approach described [How to override CellTable css](https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/google-web-toolkit/dZLk5LwnKN0).

I need to apply a border to the entire table. I can apply borders to individual cells using `.dataGridCell`.

```
/**
* Applied to every cell.
*/
.dataGridCell {
  padding: standard-cell-padding;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #6f7277;
  border-left: 1px solid #6f7277;
  border-right: 1px solid #6f7277;
  border-top: 1px solid #6f7277;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

But then in the intersections the border becomes bold and page doesn't look nice.

[image]

There is another class defined in the css as below.

```
/**
* Applied to the table.
*/  
.dataGridWidget {
}
```

It seems even I changed values for this class, it doesn't has any effect. Does any one know how to get this done?

Comment: there are also classnames for first column/cell, last column/cell and uneven and even rows. You could use border-right on the cells for example and have border-right:0 on the last column. 
The best thing is to use Chrome Developer Tools modify the styles directly and then copy them into your stylesheet for your CellTable/DataGrid

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS class names are being  obfuscated. You should use [`Client Bundles`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle) (specifically, [`CssResource`](https://developers.google.com/web-toolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideClientBundle#CssResource)) in order to ensure that the right class names are used.

Also, take a look at [this](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/cellview/client/DataGrid.Style.html).

Answer (score 0):

The intersections show up as bold because of some styles that the browser is inserting.
In Chrome they show up in inspector as `user agent stylesheet`
In particular what makes the borders appear thick in the intersections is this `border-collapse: separate;`

See [this stackoverflow link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet) that explains how to get rid of these default browser css settings.

and also [this](http://www.cssreset.com/)