# Be rid of table border - user agent is overriding style sheet

Tags: css, border, css-tables

I read this link already [What is user agent stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet)  and I've tried to copy the entire rule to the site's style sheet with no luck. I've tried giving the table itself a class and writing a rule. I've tried border:none and I've tried making the border color `#fff`.

Obviously, I'm missing the obvious.

The page is http://www.outreachnc.com/rack-locations/

Comment: Please post your code as a jsfiddle and/or paste it here... As it stands, this question is not a good format for SO. Please read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for more details.

Comment: I didn't post any code?!? (unless typing out #fff VS typing WHITE is code?!?!)

Comment: You hadn't posted any code... Merely saying "The page is http://...." is inadequate. Like I said, create a working fiddle, or post it as a code sample here. It's a pretty simple request and should be done on every one of your questions.

Answer (score 1):

This is the reason you should use firebug

```
.art-article th, .art-article td - Line 846
```

Remove `border: 1px solid #B8B8B8;`

Comment: Mr. Alien... I was using the code inspector on Chrome... thank you very much (and I do also have fire bug, thank you again).  When I was selecting the table it was showing USER AGENT was still showing as valid even though I wrote a rule.  I had not drilled down to the TD's yet.

Answer (score 0):

There was a rule for the TD's.  Yes, I missed the obvious.