# Where does this style information come from

Tags: java, css

I am debugging a web portal out of a Java project. In the resulting jsp page, a div is always not shown, the reason is because there is a "display:none" being set for it:

```
 <div class="settings_nav" style="display: none;">

  </div>
```

In the debug mode of the Chrome browser, there is a "Styles" section describes this as:

```
 element.style {
 display: none;
 }
```

Interestingly, this style information is not associated with any CSS stylesheets in Chrome debug mode, I searched through the CSS stylesheet set, there is still not hit.

Could experts give me some hint on where is the best place to find this style definition? Thanks.

Comment: Maybe by some Javascript?

Comment: is there any jquery or javascript running the page? there could be a .hide() somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not coming from a style sheet since it's an inline style on the div.
Inline styles override values from style sheets.

Could have been added through JavaScript or server side code

Comment: since it is such a huge project, do you think it makes sense to search the "javascript" subfolder using keyword "settings_nav"?

Comment: Yes, if it's using JQuery to hide it, you might find something like $(".settings_nav").hide()

Comment: @Kevin search for single quotes too: `$('.settings_nav').hide()` or better yet, just go through all instances of `.hide()` and possibly `.css(` and others like them.

Answer (score 1):

`element.style` refers to dynamically added styles; that is, as others have pointed out, added by javascript. I would look through your js files. Your best bet is to search your js directory for keywords that are involved in changing CSS. I can almost guarantee that the word 'display' is used somewhere (unless you are using jquery) and if you are really lucky maybe you'll only get a couple hits on that search term.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways in which you might see the styles applied and you can check it through the dev tools.

1. Inline style
2. [User-agent stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet)
3. Styles defined in a stylesheet
4. Using Javascript