# chrome : how to turn off user agent stylesheet settings?

Tags: css, google-chrome

I am trying to disable the **User Agent Stylesheet** in chrome. How can I turn this off/disable this?

[image]

Comment: Do you want to *hide* those rules from being listed in Developer Tools? Reasonable request. Do you want to disable those rules from being applied to your page? Bad idea, and not going to happen.

Comment: Curious why it is a bad idea to disable those rules from applying to a page. I am trying to find the root cause of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570594/input-type-number-mouse-wheel-does-not-scroll and it would be great to quickly just disable all these style sheets to help narrow down the problem.

Comment: You can override those settings in your css style sheet. for example, you can text-decoration:none in your element.style

Comment: That comment helped me the most. Thank you @Apparao!

Comment: But there are MANY user agent stylesheet rules, some with long names like margin-block-start. No obvious way to disable them all either for testing purposes or to remove all margins and paddings from navigation uls and lis.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/chrome-developer-tools/docs/settings

1. Open Chrome dev tools
2. Click gear icon on bottom right
3. In General section, check or uncheck "Show user agent styles".

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for a more in-depth view of the solution.

Comment: fwiw - this has changed some in the newest version of chrome dev tools

Comment: It's very weird: It's literally gone, despite the fact that the [current chrome docs](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/settings) still show the option `show user agent styles` in the first screenshot (first column, last option there)

Comment: So chrome seems to have completely removed this option.

Comment: Was this ever figured out? It's 2019 now and I've suddenly got no way to override an H2 bold, i.e., my css is being overridden by user agent stylesheet.

Comment: And chrome now displays auto-filled inputs as blue: !important.. great

Comment: I ran into this just now as well, moving the non-triggering CSS blocks higher in the stylesheet ended up revealing a typo in one definition which meant everything below it was being ignored.

Comment: 2021. I don't see any "General section" nor "Show user agent styles". Could you update the correct path as of 2020s ?

Comment: in Chrome v90, how to off the "User style agent" sheet. It is always blocking my popup modal, it is set to display: none in chrome version 90.