# CSS - change font-family for individual select options

Tags: jquery, html, css

Here is what I am trying to acheive:

- Standard SELECT form element
- The FIRST option will have font-family of Verdana
- All other options will have font-family of Arial
- After selecting an option, the SELECT will appear in the font-family of that option
- This is done using a combination of CSS and JS. JS is used to change the class of the SELECT so that it can apply the correct style.

I have got this working to the above requirements in Firefox and IE11 but not in Chrome 36 (Windows).

Here is a JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/KhvJc/

CSS:

```
select {
    width: 150px;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding: 5px;
    height: 30px;
}

/* when the first option is selected */
select.empty {
    color: #959595;
    font-family: Verdana;
}

/* all options except the first when the first option is selected and the select has focus */
select.empty:focus option:not(:first-child) {
    color: #282525;
    font-family: Arial;
}

/* first option when the select has focus */
select:focus option:first-child {
    color: #BDBDBD;
    font-family: Verdana;
}
```

JS:

```
$('select').change(function(){
    if($(this).val() == '')
    {
        $(this).addClass('empty');
    }
    else
    {
        $(this).removeClass('empty');
    }
}).change();
```

HTML:

```
<select>
    <option value="">Empty Option</option>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="1">Option 2</option>
    <option value="1">Option 3</option>
    <option value="1">Option 4</option>
</select>
```

As you will see, in Chrome it does not apply the `font-family` to individual options but it does manage to apply the `color`. Anybody know how to fix this?

Comment: I think I've read somewhere that chrome does not allow styling <option> elements except for color and background-color.

Comment: Are serious? Is it not possible to style the option till date. How are you even getting a colored output? Which version of Chrome? I don't see any colors?

Comment: @sarbbottam - please read the post properly, it clearly says "Chrome 36" and there is a JSFiddle link which you can test with.

Comment: My bad @GSTAR. I misinterpreted it. I read it as 'working in ``Chrome``'. Was not aware that IE and FX are allowing the ``option`` to be styled.

Comment: your fiddle doesn't seem to work??

Comment: Cross browser support for styling option tags is poor. Consider creating a widget or using an existing widget and editing its properties to get what you want. Here is an existing widget that you can try: http://brianreavis.github.io/selectize.js/

Comment: This has been logged as issue 44917 with Chromium (4 years ago so...) https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=44917

Answer (score 4):

Not certain about exact sequence of logic at OP ? Is `option:first-child` the only element whose `font-family` property is intended to be set to `Verdana` ? With other `option` elements `font-family` property set to `Arial` ? Then , after initial `select` , or `change` event , `option:first-child` `font-family` is set to `Arial` ?

The piece at OP appear to work o.k. at jsfiddle , setting `font-family` , at chrome unstable (37) , and chromium (33).

If not appear to work there , try adding

`!important`

after `font-family` property `value`, i.e.g.,

`Verdana !important;`

`Arial !important;`

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/kAdL9/

jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/guest271314/E2dze/ (applying `Monospace` and `Impact` fonts , respectively ; which may be easier to view the differences of ?)

See

[Override USER AGENT STYLE SHEET - Chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20116148/override-user-agent-style-sheet-chrome)

[chrome : how to turn off user agent stylesheet settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006356/chrome-how-to-turn-off-user-agent-stylesheet-settings)

Comment: The first option is Verdana, all other options are Arial. After selecting an option, the select element (i.e. the outer part) must be displayed in the font-family of the selected option.

Let me know if you want me to create a simple mock up, I know it is a bit confusing!

Answer (score 4):

Try this : (I've tested it in my Firefox and works fine)

```
/* For non-first options */
.not-first {
    color: #282525;
    font-family: Arial;
}

/* For first option */
.first {
    color: #BDBDBD;
    font-family: 'Times New Roman';
}
```

JavaScript codes:

```
$('option')
    .first().addClass('first')
    .siblings().addClass('not-first');

$('select').change(function(){
    $(this).attr('class', $('option:selected', this).attr('class'));
}).change();
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/KhvJc/10/)

Answer (score -1):

Add `!important` to the attribute values.