# How to turn off user agent stylesheet in chrome

Tags: google-chrome, user-agent

I was found this topic [chrome : how to turn off user agent stylesheet settings?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18006356/chrome-how-to-turn-off-user-agent-stylesheet-settings) but it can't be help for me.

In the Firefox, it's display:
[image: firefox preview]

In the Chrome, it's display:
[image: chrome preview]

Chrome automatic add UA Style Sheet:

[image]

so my icons can not display .

How to turn off it.?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Override browser form-filling and input highlighting with HTML/CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2338102/override-browser-form-filling-and-input-highlighting-with-html-css)

Answer (score 2):

try that option

```
input:-webkit-autofill,
input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
input:-webkit-autofill:focus
input:-webkit-autofill, 
textarea:-webkit-autofill,
textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover
textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
select:-webkit-autofill,
select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
  -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 0px 1000px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) inset !important;
  transition: background-color 5000s ease-in-out 0s !important;
}
@-webkit-keyframes autofill {
        to {
            background: transparent;
        }
    }

    input:-webkit-autofill,
    input:-webkit-autofill:hover, 
    input:-webkit-autofill:focus, 
    textarea:-webkit-autofill,
    textarea:-webkit-autofill:hover,
    textarea:-webkit-autofill:focus,
    select:-webkit-autofill,
    select:-webkit-autofill:hover,
    select:-webkit-autofill:focus {
        -webkit-animation-name: autofill;
        -webkit-animation-fill-mode: both;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can reset the browser default styles by using a reset.css . Try it adding this css in your HTML:

```css
/**
 * html5doctor.com Reset Stylesheet v1.6.1 (http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/)
 * Richard Clark (http://richclarkdesign.com)
 * http://cssreset.com
 */
html, body, div, span, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
abbr, address, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, samp,
small, strong, sub, sup, var,
b, i,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    border:0;
    outline:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
body {
    line-height:1;
}
article,aside,details,figcaption,figure,
footer,header,hgroup,menu,nav,section {
    display:block;
}
nav ul {
    list-style:none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes:none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content:'';
    content:none;
}
a {
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-size:100%;
    vertical-align:baseline;
    background:transparent;
}
/* change colours to suit your needs */
ins {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    text-decoration:none;
}
/* change colours to suit your needs */
mark {
    background-color:#ff9;
    color:#000;
    font-style:italic;
    font-weight:bold;
}
del {
    text-decoration: line-through;
}
abbr[title], dfn[title] {
    border-bottom:1px dotted;
    cursor:help;
}
table {
    border-collapse:collapse;
    border-spacing:0;
}
/* change border colour to suit your needs */
hr {
    display:block;
    height:1px;
    border:0;
    border-top:1px solid #cccccc;
    margin:1em 0;
    padding:0;
}
input, select {
    vertical-align:middle;
}
```