# input type="number" mouse wheel does not scroll

Tags: html, input

I'm stumped why the mousewheel will not increment/decrement the value in a simple form element.

```html
<input type="number" step="0.125" min="0" max="0.875">
```

It works on this snippet just fine, but not when I create a simple generic html document:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input type="number" step="0.125" min="0" max="0.875">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

When I view this in several browsers, the mousewheel does not scroll. I've disabled browser extensions and such as well. Several other machines around me behave the same way.

**What causes this to not work? Is this an OS/browser issue?**

I almost feel like this might be something deeper, possibly the type of mouse/driver issue?

---

What I have tested on:

- Win 7
- Chrome - fail
- Firefox - fail
- Firefox Dev Edition - fail
- Safari - pass
- IE11 - fail
- IE9 - fail
- OSX
- Chrome - fail
- Safari - fail
- Firefox - fail

Comment: It's worth pointing out that even today, not all browsers support the new HTML5 input types.

Comment: That might be worth pointing out, but it works right here on this page and it works in various generic examples I've seen around the web.

Comment: Check this out, may be helpful: http://caniuse.com/#search=number

Comment: Well aware of caniuse, additionally, it lists as "supported" for the several browsers I have tried.

Comment: I'm able to reproduce this. Curious what the underlying issue is.

Comment: What browser/version are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Snippet runs in an IFRAME. Put your code into IFRAME and it will work too. Why - I don't know but it works.

i.e.

http://codecorner.galanter.net/bla2.htm - doesn't work (code by itself)
http://codecorner.galanter.net/bla.htm - works - previous page in an IFRAME

EDIT: Here's a demo of it working in Chrome 41: http://codecorner.galanter.net/bla_mousescroll.mp4

**EDIT 2:** I think I figured it out, and it's not IFRAMEs. In order for scroll event to happen - actual content has to be scrollable. For example if you redo your example like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <form action="" style="width:200px;overflow:scroll">
    <div style="width:300px">
            <input type="number" step="0.125" min="0" max="0.875">
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

where container form is smaller then its content - DIV - the scrolling wheel works on number field: http://codecorner.galanter.net/bla3.htm

Comment: I think you maybe missed something - what browser/os? It does not work for me.

Comment: @pspahn Chrome on Windows (the only browser where number field reliably works for me). I can use arrow buttons to change number in both pages, but mouse scroll button works only in iframed page.

Comment: Hmm, cant get this to work, even in chrome. Up/down arrows work, mouse click works, no mousewheel though.

Comment: @Shoe: Posted a small demo

Comment: I tried it. It works. Now I am just even more confused. Nice find!

Comment: Stabbing in the dark here, but I'm guessing there is a browser stylesheet doing something to the `:focus` state.

Comment: @YuriyGalanter Aha! Works in chrome now with the scrolling on the content. Nice find.

Comment: Something else I've noticed is that on occasion (at least in Chrome) mouse scrolling sometimes does work as expected with default styles. I'm not sure what I do to make it work, though.

Answer (score 2):

To avoid the browser issue altogether, you might try using the [jQuery mousewheel](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-mousewheel) plugin to manually change your input value. For example:

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.1.3.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.mousewheel.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scroll.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form action="">
        <input id="myInput" type="number" step="0.125" min="0" max="0.875">
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**scroll.js**

```
$(function() {
    $('#myInput').on("mousewheel", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        $this = $(this);
        $inc = parseFloat($this.attr('step'));
        $max = parseFloat($this.attr('max'));
        $min = parseFloat($this.attr('min'));
        $currVal = parseFloat($this.val());

        // If blank, assume value of 0
        if (isNaN($currVal)) {
            $currVal = 0.0;
        }

        // Increment or decrement numeric based on scroll distance
        if (event.deltaFactor * event.deltaY > 0) {
            if ($currVal + $inc <= $max) {
                $this.val($currVal + $inc);
            }
        } else {
            if ($currVal - $inc >= $min) {
                $this.val($currVal - $inc);
            }
        }
    });
});
```

Works for me in both Chrome and Firefox. The `mousewheel` event can be triggered when the mouse is hovering over the input as well, not just when it is selected.

Answer (score 1):

So I think I figured it out.

First I copied your code into a html document and opened it in Chrome, and the increment didn't work.
Second I removed everything from the code except the input box, still didn't work.

Then I injected that code into random websites using the chrome inspector, I tried it on gmail, reddit and my own website. Gmail worked, reddit worked, but my own website didn't work.

So then I disabled javascript and it didn't work anywhere.

So to answer your question, stackoverflow / many other sites use javascript that automatically add that functionality to number inputs.

Comment: This may be entirely true, but it should still be working without javascript in Chrome as it is native behavior.

Answer (score 0):

You only need to declare an "onmousewheel" event on the input element. No JavaScript needed.

```html
<label for="wheeltest">Value</label>
<input type="number" step="0.125" min="0" max="0.875" onmousewheel>
```