# Unable to scroll <input type="number"/> in static html file

Tags: html, input

```
<html><body><input type="number" value="1" autofocus/></body></html>
```

On an [online environment](https://jsfiddle.net/jv5k3v2n/), I'm able to hover over the input box and use the scroll wheel to change the value.

But if I save the content locally as a .html file and open it with Chrome/Safari, I will not able to change the value via scrolling.

Why is this the case?

Comment: It is not due to being online or local. It's something else. I served that HTML locally and I still can't scroll it. Must be the `iframe` situation on jsfiddle or something else. But *not* the fact that it is being served via `file://`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [input type="number" mouse wheel does not scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29570594/input-type-number-mouse-wheel-does-not-scroll)

Comment: @Liadco that question's answers does not seem to work (still can't scroll)