# Style rule in chrome debugger

Tags: css, stylesheet, google-chrome-devtools

Here is picture in chrome:
[image: chrome debugger]

I just woder what does `user stylesheet` mean here. The case is that I am 100% sure that these classes does not exists in my stylesheets (it was before). I thought It comes from cache but it remains even after cache is cleared. Any ideas? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First of all, [read this definition](http://webdesign.about.com/od/userstylesheets/a/aa010906.htm) of what a `user style sheet` is. It is an extra stylesheet to help you (the user) browse the web. Hence if you prefer certain CSS settings over what the web page designer intended, you can overrule those settings with your own.

This `user stylesheet` that you found, may therefore just be a local CSS file on your pc.

Therefore we need to know: where did you find that .CSS file?

If the same file is in this location:

```
PC: C:UsersYourUsernameAppDataLocalGoogleChromeUser DataDefaultUser StyleSheetsCustom.css

MAC: ~/Library/Application Support/Google/Chrome/Default/User StyleSheets/Custom.css
```

Then the answer is:

*The file above is, as it sounds, a CSS file that you can modify and add your own custom styles to, to change the look and feel of your Google Chrome Web Inspector.*

Which means that with that specific stylesheet you can change the look of your Google Chrome Web Inspector.
So it has nothing to do with the website you are inspecting, only with how your web inspector looks (it is built with HTML, CSS and JavaScript).

You can read about it [here](http://darcyclarke.me/design/skin-your-chrome-inspector/). (Google Chrome version 33 does not feature custom stylesheets)

It could also very well be the case that Google Chrome implements some other `user stylesheet` that is stored somewhere else on your pc (but I wouldn't know where exactly).

Note that the inspector also shows `user agent stylesheets` which is the default stylesheet that your browser implements. You can read about those in this question: [What is user agent stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet)

Comment: That was close. I don't used Inspector's stylesheets so stylesheet in `Chrome\User Data\Default\User StyleSheets` was empty. But I did global search on my PC and found same rules quite a few in `Extensions` folder. But that was not a case also. Anyway I just copied that rule to my regular stylesheet with needed settings. That changed them. So it is partly solved. Though I still would like to know where those rules comes from.

Comment: @Saulius: I would like to know that too: I have no clue where it comes from. Maybe somebody else knows.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible that the http server itself has cached the previous version of the file and is serving it.

Reload and check the headers in the Network tab, so you can get the full picture. Or if you are using development environment, you can restart the server - just to be sure.

Comment: Thanks. Just in case I restarted server. Didn't change anything. Case is that other browsers didn't have this style so it should be chrome problem.