# where is the header style defined?

Tags: css

While coding I always have to change the headers (`<h1> <h2> <h3>`) etc.. as I never like how they are styled, but where is the information for the header styles kept?

Obviously the headers are not styled in my CSS so I then thought that maybe it's something to do with the `DOCTYPE` or other code before `<head>` but removing all these didn't affect the header style at all!

So plain and simple; where is the header style defined?!

Comment: @EvanTrimboli ahh didn't see that!

Comment: You can also read here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet

Comment: You can see recommended and browser specific default sheets here: https://github.com/sw4/revert.css