# Remove line breaks inside JSTL <c:forEach>

Tags: java, html, css, jstl

I have modified `<input type="submit">` to look like a hyperlink.

**CSS:**

```
input[type="submit"].searchitem {
    background: none;
    border: none;
    color: blue;
    cursor: pointer;
    padding: 0px;
}

input[type="submit"].searchitem:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

**JSTL:**

```
<c:forEach var="searchItem" items="${searchResults}">
    <form action="view-schedule.jsp" method="post">
        <input type="hidden" name="movieid" value="${searchItem.movieId}" />
        <input type="submit" value="${searchItem.movieTitle}" class="searchitem" />
    </form>
</c:forEach>
```

**Firefox Inspector:**

```
<form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

    <input type="hidden" value="4" name="movieid"></input>
    <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="INSURGENT"></input>

</form>
<form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

    <input type="hidden" value="2" name="movieid"></input>
    <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="INTERSTELLAR"></input>

</form>
<form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

    <input type="hidden" value="9" name="movieid"></input>
    <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="MINIONS"></input>

</form>
<form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

    <input type="hidden" value="6" name="movieid"></input>
    <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="MOCKINGJAY: PART I"></input>

</form>
<form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

    <input type="hidden" value="3" name="movieid"></input>
    <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="PENGUINS OF MADAGASCAR"></input>

</form>
<form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

    <input type="hidden" value="8" name="movieid"></input>
    <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="WHITE BIRD IN A BLIZZARD"></input>

</form>
```

**Output:**

[image]

But it's displaying a blank space between the search results. I don't think I have a `<br />` anywhere.

(It was working okay with scriptlet for-each, but I am trying to convert to JSTL).

Comment: Is that line break due to `hidden` element ? Did u `inspect` it ?

Comment: @OO7 Hi, I added the Firefox Inspector to the post, there does not seem to be a `<br />` as well.

Comment: Yeah, but why there is blank line before & after `<input>` element ? Did u check for the same in other browsers ?

Comment: I don't think the blank lines there are the culprit. HTML is not WYSIWYG after all.

Comment: Is there any CSS property which sets `line-height` like property ? I m not sure but, u can check is this happens due to CSS ?

Comment: Hi, let me check my CSS for that property and I will report back. Same behavior in Chrome btw.

Comment: @OO7 No `line-height` property present in any of my CSS. I searched for `height`, but it's for an unrelated class. Also, it only alters height by `2px`, which is too small for that gap, so that's why I don't think it's the `height` property as well.

Comment: U *didn't gave any style for form* that's why it has some **style applied** from **User Agent** on `form` HTML element. See my answer & try sample HTML I gave. Inspect it in Crome or see `computed` style in Firefox inspector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As there is no style applicable to `form`, it has `margin-bottom` from **user agent stylesheet** 
like

```
form {
    margin-bottom: 1em;
}
```

replace this with below for good look

```
form {
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}
```

Try this

```
<html>
    <head>
    <title>Test Line Break</title>
    <style>
        form{
            margin-bottom:5px;
        }
        input[type="submit"].searchitem {
            background: none;
            border: none;
            color: blue;
            cursor: pointer;
            padding: 0px;
        }

        input[type="submit"].searchitem:hover {
            text-decoration: underline;
        }
    </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="movieid"></input>
            <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="INTERSTELLAR"></input>

        </form>
        <form method="post" action="view-schedule.jsp">

            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="movieid"></input>
            <input class="searchitem" type="submit" value="INTERSTELLAR"></input>

        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

That's why u get breaks in button.

Comment: I added `form { margin-bottom: 0px; }` and it worked. I have now also read about [user agent styleshhet](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet), thanks for the explanation. Upvoted and marked as accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

just add this to your CSS

```
 form {
    margin-bottom: 0;
 }
```