# space between tags in html

Tags: html, servlets

**I am using html in servlet to develop a registration form but I am getting this huge space between header and my table, I don't know what is wrong, I tried setting margin to zero but nothing is happening please help. I am uploading both files, first one is .java file and second one is browser output.**[image]

[image]

Comment: use inspection tools in your browser to find out what takes that space.

Comment: @Kamil, can u tell me how to use inspection tool in my browser.

Comment: in firefox and chrome press F12. then on the very left there is a button (in chrome it has loupe icon), click on it, and then click on empty space.

Comment: Show the source of the html page. Tt will be much more easier to analize the error with the html source code instead of a picture.

Comment: @Kamil, to my surprise Kamil, it is showing 6 <br> after <h1> tag , how can I remove them each time I call this servlet

Comment: @kamil, why does it automatically, i mean html code in java by itself inserts so many breaks.

Comment: @kamil, it always gives five breaks everytime I visit this page.

Comment: Inspect `suspected` element & look at **[User Agent](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet)** style. May be there is something in userAgent style which produces this space. Also look at [CSS2.1 User Agent Style Sheet Defaults](http://css-class.com/test/css/defaults/UA-style-sheet-defaults.htm)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Wrong break tag, it should be closed

```
     <br/>
```

My guess:
Remove them, they are used wrong, you cannot use them inside a table, and outside a td tag. That should solve your problem.

And some tips:

1. Why you are using servlet to generate html? This way you will have big problems in future. You should be using some viewResolver, like Freemarker, jsp or velocity.
2. Tag center is "deprecated", don't use it. Replace it with a css styles.
3. Your table is missing tbody tag, it should be

   ```
    <table>
     <tbody>
      <tr></tr>
     </tbody>
    <table>
   ```

But writing forms in a table is an antipattern. Here you can find some bootstrap example, how to do it right using only classes and css:
http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-forms.php

3. Use FF or Chrome developer tools , Firebug(FF), F12 in Chrome. Thanks to them you will find your problem.

If you are using Chrome, click F12, you will have an window popup at the bottom of page. First tab is Elements, click on mignifying glass and select your table. You will see DOM tree of your app. When you click on a tag you will see how many space it takes: it's size, paddings and margins, you can even manipulate those values on fly. When you will find the reason, you just need to create some CSS to fix your bug. That will be easy to google.

Comment: I know that using HTML in java is bad, but I am working on a small school project in which we are not supposed to use JSP. so thatz why I am doing like this.

Comment: thanks a lot man, I removed all <br> tags and used </tbody> and it worked, thanks again...

Answer (score 0):

Use "`<h1 style="margin:0;">`" instead of "`<h1>`" for reduce margin around title.

Use "`<table border="0\" height="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">`" instead of "`<table>`" for reducing paddings around the table.

These two modification may reduce space between title and table.

Answer (score 0):

The center tag is deprecated. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/center
Using tables for formatting is no longer a best practice. 
Try something like this instead.

```
<h1>Registration Form</h1>
<form>
<p><label for="id">ID: </label><input type="text" name="id" /></p>
<p><label for="fName">First Name: <input type="text" name="fName"></label></p>
</form>
```