# Why is this table 2px too large?

Tags: css

I can't figure it out, why is this table 102px and not 100px in height? Is there another css attribute I need to set otherthan:

```
table {
    border-spacing:0;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
```

example: https://jsfiddle.net/0enwstw7/2/

Comment: Can you post the rest of your code (HTML, CSS, JS) here so that we don't have to go to an external site? You can even put it in a snippet to demonstrate exactly what you're asking about.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be padding on the `<td>` tag assigned by default.  This should fix it:

```
td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

Comment: Upvote for being first off the blocks with the right answer. You beat me by a few seconds.

Answer (score 0):

The `<td>` element defaults to having 1px padding, which adds a pixel on each side to make 102px total.

Remove it with `td{padding:0;}`

Answer (score 0):

It's the **padding of the td** that adds another 2px;

You have set the up div to be 100px but you are measuring the table.

You can set the padding of the td to 0;

```
td  {
padding: 0px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing implicit td padding which is included into overall size of the table. Sufficed to add some directive like this:

```
td {
    padding: 0;
}
```

see: https://jsfiddle.net/0enwstw7/3/

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this.

[image]

Your browser (e.g. Chrome) has its own stylesheet and that's why it adds that `border-spacing: 2px;` to the table.

If you want more information about browser specific stylesheet, take a look at [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet).

And Yes. Like lots of people here already mentioned it, you can override the setting by adding

```
td {
  padding: 0px;
}
```

BUT I still think it's important to know WHY this happened.

Hope this helps.