# How to make uneditable/readonly class in CSS(SCSS, JS)?

Tags: css, sass, module, styles, readonly

I saw not editable class styles on the [site](https://privatbank.ua/ru/sendmoney) on chat pane. 
And the classes themselves were dynamically changing. 
**How to make same?**

[image]

Comment: No @Pete Some non editable style also we have.

Comment: @AnishSharma Seems to be a bug with chrome and iframes: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38201898/chrome-developer-tools-some-styles-from-css-file-grayed-out-uneditable (or where users have an error in their stylesheet somewhere) but I don't think it's done on purpose