# asp TextBox margin not displaying properly in Chrome and IE but works in Firefox

Tags: css, asp.net, textbox

I have a Panel that contains a bunch of TextBoxes. I have added the margin attribute to my CSS file. Currently, I can get it to display properly in Firefox, but when I view it in IE and Chrome there is no margin.

**Textbox**

`asp:TextBox ID="txtInvoiceDate" Font-Bold="true" runat="server" CssClass="TextBox"></asp:TextBox>`

**CSS**

`.TextBox
{
    margin: 5px;
}`

Initially when I save the project, it will display the margins. When I refresh the page, the margins disappear.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It looks like the -webkit-margin attributes have been deprecated. Unless I'm missing something

Answer (score 0):

After more research, I found that the margin attribute was being overridden by the User Agent Style Sheet. I added some new CSS to the file and voila...it's properly working.

I found the answer via [What is user agent stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet)