# Why do (disabled) buttons with color:inherit not follow disabled style?

Tags: css, css-specificity

As seen in this fiddle, a property of `color: inherit` on `button` prevents a disabled button appearing as disabled.

I thought specificity would mean that disabled buttons still appeared disabled. How does this override the user-agent styling and how would it be possible to make them appear enabled again? Manually assigning a color to `button:disabled {color:GreyText}` does not work.

https://jsfiddle.net/zzhLhkjx/

Compare this to https://jsfiddle.net/g46kg6ev/ which shows a disabled button with greyed out text. Just specifying color to inherit stops that behaviour.

Comment: `button:disabled {color:green}` works fine. If still not, add `!important`

Comment: disabled is a state, am not sure why you are talking about CSS and specifity ?

Comment: Inherit from what? - Works fine for me - https://jsfiddle.net/yqcxok85/

Comment: Perhaps you are looking for `initial`? - https://jsfiddle.net/y7wdrvsu/

Comment: From an answer (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet) by @JukkaK.Korpela "User agent style sheets are overridden by anything that you set in your own style sheet. They are just the rock bottom: in the absence of any style sheets provided by the page or by the user, the browser still has to render the content somehow, and the user agent style sheet just describes this." This being said, I'm still not sure *where* your button is inherting styles from. Computed `color` styles for the `body` tag are `black`, but this is also a user-agent style.

Comment: It's the disabled style that isn't working. It doesn't appear disabled.

Comment: Compare to https://jsfiddle.net/g46kg6ev/ which has greyed out text because it is disabled. Just specifying color:inherit stops the button:disabled styling. Why?

Comment: Easily demonstrated here: https://jsfiddle.net/zzhLhkjx/2/ - notice the cascade order to discount specificity as the issue. I mentioned in my previous comment that the button was probably inheriting styles from the computed styles of the `body` which, *for some reason I cannot explain for you unfortunately*, must have more **weight** than the *user-agent* style; which, under normal circumstances, would indeed have more *specificity*.

Comment: @UncaughtTypeError So without manually specifying a button:disabled style the disabled style disappears despite color only being set to inherit. So even without any other styling specified, the non-user agent rule for buttons overrides the more specific userAgentStyle of disabled buttons?

Comment: By all indications it does appear so. As I understand it, any author defined style will *over-qualify* any user-agent style regardless of specificity - since author styles always carry more **weight** than user-agent styles.

Comment: Feel free to provide that as an answer. I'm disappointed this question was so quickly downvoted and voted to close since it doesn't appear to have a trivial answer, although in retrospect it didn't help that I was trying GreyText not grayText which through me off track since it would have worked with GrayText as you demonstrated.

Comment: What downvotes? I shamelessly copied and pasted my last comment word for word :) I hope that still passes as your answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I understand it, any *author* defined styles will *over-qualify* any *user-agent* style regardless of *specificity* - since author styles always carry more **weight** than user-agent styles.

[JSFiddle demonstration to rule out any specificity doubts](http://%20jsfiddle.net/zzhLhkjx/2)

---

More on user-agent stylesheet weight from an answer ([What is user agent stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet)) by @JukkaK.Korpela

> "User agent style sheets are overridden by anything that you set in
>   your own style sheet. They are just the rock bottom: in the absence of
>   any style sheets provided by the page or by the user, the browser
>   still has to render the content somehow, and the user agent style
>   sheet just describes this."