# Favicon not visible - Chrome overwriting my stylesheet

Tags: wordpress, google-chrome, favicon

I am having troubles with my favicon. I have a WordPress site and I use this code to display the favicon in my functions.php:

```
function add_my_favicon() {
   $favicon_path = get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/favicon.ico';
   echo '<link class="favicon" rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="' . $favicon_path . '?" />';
   echo '<link class="favicon" rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="' . $favicon_path . '?" />';
}
add_action( 'wp_head', 'add_my_favicon' ); //front end
add_action( 'admin_head', 'add_my_favicon' ); //admin end
```

Everything good so far. It works on my homepage site but it does not on all the other sites. For example the favicon is missing on my product detail site. The html source code is loaded correctly everytime but it seems that chrome is somehow overwriting my stylesheet with:

user agent stylesheet:

```
link {
    display: none;
}
```

It tried also with Firefox and there it works without problems. Only Chrome is buggy. I disabled also Adblock for my site and still the same issue.

Any more ideas?

Comment: you can simply add your favicon using Appearance -> Customize. add the Favicon Icon under "Site Icon" and you are done.

Answer (score 0):

You can add your favicon under `Appearance -> Customize -> Site Identity -> Site Icon`

Upload 512 x 512 icon and this icon taking as your site Favicon icon

Comment: Yes I know and I also tried this but I have still the same problem. This is why i tried another way by modifiying functions.php. Forgot to mention this sorry.

Comment: @Nicola then there should be error in coding standards. please refer to the wordpress coding standards. why you downvote my answer as it is the best way to do so. ?

Comment: @Nicola You never said you tried this in the original ticket.  We are not mind readers so down voting a suggestion like that is poor form.

Answer (score 0):

You can read more about user agent stylesheets here;
[What is user agent stylesheet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet)

Have you tried adding some css to your theme? Without a link to your website it's impossible for anyone here to identify exactly which bit of css you would need to change but setting the right class to display: block; or display: inline-block;  should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

Just call the function `add_my_favicon` at your **header.php**. It does nothing when you are calling in **wp_head** & **admin_head** action. 
Please find the below code as example :

```
<html <?php language_attributes(); ?>>
<head>
<meta charset="<?php bloginfo( 'charset' ); ?>">
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="profile" href="http://gmpg.org/xfn/11">
<link rel="pingback" href="<?php bloginfo( 'pingback_url' ); ?>">

<?php
    add_my_favicon();
    wp_head();
?>
</head>
```

Hope it helps.