# Manually added CSS rule greyed out in chrome only

Tags: css, google-chrome

When you select an element and click the + icon to add a rule and without you having entered something, how is it possible that it is already greyed out and thus not applied? It's applied on a div with class tabs-container which contains some html.
[image]

Comment: Different browsers have different default styles for elements. If you have a div without any styling in chrome, the default display value is block. Here an question to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-user-agent-stylesheet

Answer (score 0):

Correct me If I misunderstood, but by default the gray section shows you the default styles of an element which in case of a div is display:block, as you can see that declaration is coming from user agent style sheet that is the browser default styles..

Comment: I think, this could also be a comment dude.