# Can't understand from where <a> tag inherits black color?

Tags: html, css

just add color: inherit to link tag. As a result, link tag inherits black color. But can't understand from where? Can't  find answer in devtools. Do somebody know? Thanks

```css
a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
 <body>
        <nav>
            <ul class="nav-list">
                <li>
                    <a href="#welcome-section">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#projects">Work</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

Comment: In inherits it from the default user-agent stylesheet which has `body { color: black; }`. Your user-agent stylesheet is embedded within your browser. See here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-a-user-agent-stylesheet

Comment: you always inherit from the direct parent. In this case `li`. Sicne `li` has no color declared the standard color applies which is black in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by default, css gives a black color to the text.
Since `<a>` is being used within the body, it inherits the features of the parent tag `<body>`

if you change the attributes of any element/s between `<body>` and `<a>` (for instance `<li> <ul>` etc.), then `<a>` will inherit the properties of the first direct parent.

Comment: actually body inherits from html

Comment: and the default the color is not black. Its preset from the browser stylesheet. If the browser has a darkmode as example the default color could also be white.

Answer (score 1):

inherit keyword inherits the property of the parent element.
By default the text, body, ul, li, nav has color property as black

color: black

so by giving

```
a{
color:inherit;
}
```

it inherits the property of its immediate parent. As in your code, its immediate parent is

```
 <li>
```

so if the list has the color,  tag will inherit its color. else it will inherit the property of the main parent i.e the

```
<body>
```

Have a look changing the color of body and li here. You will understand It better [Test it live here](https://codepen.io/BadalChangba/pen/YzGBypP)

and This link shows that by default body has black color [Follow the comments given in codepen you will understand it better here](https://codepen.io/BadalChangba/pen/wvzNKgJ)

Comment: Thanks, Badal for extensive reply :) Now I understand this topic very clearly.

Comment: Hope it's of your help and the answer to your question.