# Inherit keyword not working with classes in css

Tags: html, css

Okay so as the title says I've been trying to use the `inherit` keyword with the `h1`'s that have the class called "`special`" but it doesn't work as long as I decide to use `id`'s on them. Can anyone please explain me why?

```
<div class="container">
    <h1>Just a text wrapped inside heading-1 tag</h1>
    <h1 class="special">Just a text wrapped inside heading-1 tag</h1>
    <h1>Just a text wrapped inside heading-1 tag</h1>
    <h1>Just a text wrapped inside heading-1 tag</h1>
    <h1 class="special">Just a text wrapped inside heading-1 tag</h1>
</div>
```

Below is the styling

```
  <style>
    .container {
      color: blue;
    }

    .container h1{
      color: green;
    }
    .special {
      color: inherit;
    }
  </style>
```

Comment: `.container h1` (class selector plus type selector) is more specific than `.special` (just a class selector) so overrides it.

Comment: As the comment from @Quentin it works with class selector but you've overwrite the style.

Comment: See here how the inherit works https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65763644/cant-understand-from-where-a-tag-inherits-black-color/65764196#65764196

Comment: @Quentin Thanks! doing it like this `.container .special`  worked!