# Why <input> Does Not Inherit Color?

Tags: html

I have the HTML below. In order to get green text in the text `input` I have to inherit the `color` from the parent `<span>`; otherwise, the text `input` would have black text. Why is this necessary? Why doesn't the `input` element just inherit the `color` property from its parent?

Are there other other elements that don't inherit properties from their ancestors?

```html
<p>Without color: inherit;</p>
<div style="color: darkgreen;">
    <input type="text" value="Displays black" />
</div>

<p>With color: inherit;</p>
<div style="color: darkgreen;">
    <input type="text" style="color: inherit;" value="Displays green" />
</div>
```

Comment: Sounds quite broad to make an extensive list, but textarea and anchors **with `href`** do that too.

Comment: because input elements ( as many others ) have a default style

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's your user agent stylesheet which is overriding the color setting on the input.

Here are the `input` rules from Chrome's user agent stylesheet:

[image]

Note the rule:

```css
input {
    color: -internal-light-dark(black, white);
}
```

This is more specific than your `color` rule, so overrides it.

Browsers are free to implement whatever they want in their own stylesheets, so this depends from browser to browser.

You can [read more here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-a-user-agent-stylesheet)

Answer (score 1):

CSS applies styles based on [the cascade, specificity, and inheritance](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Learn/CSS/Building_blocks/Cascade_and_inheritance).

In short, browsers have a style sheet (check out @Joundill's answer) that they apply before applying any site styles and it probably includes something like:

```
input {
  color: black;
}
```

This style takes preference over your inline style on the parent `span`.

Look into applying a [CSS reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) to reset the browser style sheet.