# React-Router-Dom causes webpage not to fill all available space

Tags: reactjs, web

im new to react and just getting used to changing between webpages using react-router. However whenever I install react-router using 'npx I react-router-dom' and then reload the webpage I get white bars at the edge of the page even though I haven't changed any code.

//Before react router install
[no bars](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u5eW3.png)

//After installing - white bars at edge

[White bars at edge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FhXR0.png)

Thanks any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Just for future reference if anyone is struggling with this iv'e found a post here:[Encountering white-space at top of react-app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65770679/encountering-white-space-at-top-of-react-app)

which fixed the issue