# Override user agent style for li element

Tags: html, css, doctype

I have the following html.

```
   <div class="alert alert-error" role="alert">        
        <ul>
            <li>This is test message.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

I am using bootstrap alert. Alert styles are override in custom css to add `ban-circle` before the alert message.

```
.alert {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: white;
}   

.alert-error {
    background-color: rgb(186, 39, 39);
}

    /*Using a Bootstrap glyphicon as ban-circle*/
    .alert-error li:before {
        content: "\e090"; 
        font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
        padding-right: 5px;
    }
```

UI shows the ban circle before alert message, but it also shows dot before the ban-circle. The dot is coming from user agent style sheet. I have `<!DOCTYPE html>` as suggested in this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-a-user-agent-stylesheet)

[image]

How do I get rid of the dot from the User Agent Style?

Comment: `.alert-error ul { list-style: none; }` should do the trick.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get rid of the dot by using list-style-type property of CSS value none. You can read further about the property [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_list-style-type.asp).

I have used it in the following code:

```css
.alert {
    padding: 5px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
    color: white;
}

.alert-error {
    background-color: rgb(186, 39, 39);
}

/*Using a Bootstrap glyphicon as ban-circle*/

.alert-error li:before {
    content: "\e090";
    font-family: 'Glyphicons Halflings';
    padding-right: 5px;
}

ul {
    list-style-type: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <!-- Required meta tags -->
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./style.css">

    <title>Hello, world!</title>
</head>

<body>
    <div class="alert alert-error" role="alert">        
        <ul>
            <li>This is test message.</li>
        </ul>
    </div>

</body>

</html>
```