# Unexpected white background on font-awesome icon

Tags: html, css, icons, font-awesome, styling

When I'm, including a font-awesome icon, there's this unexpected white background that I can't remove. Any ideas on how to remove it?

HTML Code:

```
<div class="notifications-window" id="close-notifications">
<div class="notifications-header">
    <h4>Notifications</h4>
    <button type="button" onclick="closenotifs()"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></button>
</div>
<div class="notifications-details">
    <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
    <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
</div>
```

CSS Code:

```
.notifications-window {
width: 350px;
border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
background-color: rgb(160, 156, 156);
color: #fff;
border-collapse: collapse;
border-radius: 5px;
text-align: center;
list-style-type: none;
display: inline-block;
}

.notifications-window p {
font-size: small;
padding: 5px;
background: rgb(141, 136, 136);
border-radius: 5px;
margin: 5px;
}

.notifications-details {
overflow-y: auto;
max-height: 350px;
}

.fa-window-close {
display: inline-block;
float: right;
justify-content: right;
cursor: pointer;
text-decoration: none;
text-align: center;
color: #000;
background-color: #fff;
border: none;
outline: none;
transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, 
            transform 150ms ease;
-webkit-appearance: none;
-moz-appearance: none;
}
```

I'm attaching an image of how the icon looks like after styling

https://i.stack.imgur.com/bfBW6.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The background of the button is added by `User Agent Stylesheet`. You can explore more about `user agent stylesheet` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-a-user-agent-stylesheet).

However you can remove the background of the button by writing your own styles.
For this I wrote a `.button` class for button and also removed `background-color: #fff;` from your `.fa-window-close` class. Try this out;

CSS:

```
.notifications-window {
            width: 350px;
            border: 3px solid rgb(0, 0, 0);
            background-color: rgb(160, 156, 156);
            color: #fff;
            border-collapse: collapse;
            border-radius: 5px;
            text-align: center;
            list-style-type: none;
            display: inline-block;
        }

            .notifications-window p {
                font-size: small;
                padding: 5px;
                background: rgb(141, 136, 136);
                border-radius: 5px;
                margin: 5px;
            }

        .notifications-details {
            overflow-y: auto;
            max-height: 350px;
        }

        .fa-window-close {
            display: inline-block;
            float: right;
            justify-content: right;
            cursor: pointer;
            text-decoration: none;
            text-align: center;
            color: #000;
            /*background-color: #fff;*/
            border: none;
            outline: none;
            transition: background 250ms ease-in-out, transform 150ms ease;
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            -moz-appearance: none;
        }
        .button {
            background: transparent;
            border: none;
        }
```

HTML:

```
<div class="notifications-window" id="close-notifications">
    <div class="notifications-header">
        <h4>Notifications</h4>
        <button type="button" onclick="closenotifs()" class="button"><i class="fas fa-window-close"></i></button>
    </div>
    <div class="notifications-details">
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
        <p>Congratulations! Login Reward: 2 credits</p>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Comment: ah, that worked, thank you so much

but is it not same as removing those elements in the .fa-window-close itself?

why doesn't it work that way?

Comment: I am happy that it worked for you. You need to [Accept Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)