# CSS background-clip content-box, what's the shape of the content here?

Tags: css

I'm try to make a button circle made by a circle and a ring.

https://codepen.io/gremo/pen/BaYqRaE

So here is my CSS. I use `background-clip: content-box` because the background should extend up to the content box, the `box-shadow` then makes the ring.

```
.btn-circle {
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 9999px;
  border: 4px solid transparent;
  background-color: #f7e938;
  width: 4rem;
  height: 4rem;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 0px 4px #f7e938;
  background-clip: content-box;
}
```

The problem is that the button becomes an oval:

[image: Oval]

As soon as i change it to `padding-box` it seems to work. Just curious about that.What's the shape of the `content-box` here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like the automatic padding added to the element was uneven. Setting a padding value such as `padding: 2px` solved the issue on the codepen for me.

[image]

Seems like it is coming from default values in User Agent Stylesheet:

[image]

Refer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-a-user-agent-stylesheet) for more details regarding this.