# Why does my button have a box shadow around it?

Tags: html, css

Why does my button have a shadow around it?

I am trying to create a blue button with the border being the same color as the button itself. When you hover over the button it moves up by 3px and when you click it moves back down.

```css
button {
  background-color: var(--accent);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0;
  border-color: var(--accent);
  color: var(--background);
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

button:active {
  transform: translateY(-0px);
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Comment: what's the value of `--accent` ? is it a transparent color (opacity < 1)?

Comment: @FabrizioCalderan the value of accent is #007bff.

Comment: Your button moves because you set a translateY on hover

Comment: @Sfili_81 that is the intended purpose.

Comment: Have a look at the user agent stylesheet. The default styling for buttons and other elements is styled by default there. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12582624/what-is-a-user-agent-stylesheet

Comment: The reason for closing this question should be Typo, as the original question incorrectly refers to a shadow. Its also a mistake that cannot be reproduced, but since the mistake comes from a typo, I feel typo is the correct reason to close.

Comment: Hm. A "typo" is a slip of the finger, an accidental typing mistake – like "Lrland". Taking a stab at where an issue stems from, and being wrong, is not a typo.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I see no box shadow in Safari, Firefox, or Chrome. But perhaps you're referring to the two-tone border color? That's happening because default browser styles use `border-style: outset`. Try instead doing `border-style: solid`:

```css
button {
  border-style: solid;
  border-radius: 10px;
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}
button:active {
  transform: translateY(-0px);
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing >border-color< would do it

```css
button {
  background-color: var(--accent);
  border-radius: 10px;
  box-shadow: 0;      
  color: var(--background);
  padding-top: 7px;
  padding-bottom: 7px;
  padding-left: 15px;
  padding-right: 15px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: transform 0.3s;
}

button:hover {
  transform: translateY(-3px);
}

button:active {
  transform: translateY(-0px);
}
```

```html
<button>Button</button>
```

Answer (score -2):

try setting the box-shadow to none

Comment: That did not work