# Remove margin of my component on Angular (User Agent Stylesheet is overriding)

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material

When testing the components I just made, I realized there is a space between the header and the component. Also, I set dark theme so it's easier to see. Then, I realized that the component has a couple problems. It doesn't fill the whole page and it has a 16px margin on top and bottom.

To fix that, I made a `:host > *` style to change the height to be 100% and and remove the margin. It worked regarding the height, ***however***, it totally ignored the margin.

I checked and User Agent Stylesheet is replacing it.

[image]

*app.component.scss*

```scss
:host > * {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0!important;
    padding: 0!important;
}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31982381/17038313

Comment: @oksd Eh, that even comes by default. It was already there and checked just in case. You can see it in the screenshot too. That's not the solution.