# HTML5 Boilerplate and 960.gs should I include reset.css?

Tags: html, css, 960.gs, html5boilerplate, css-reset

Am starting a project using HTML5 Boilerplate and 960.gs.

When implementing 960.gs should I copy over reset.css or just have normalize.css, or keep both! Sorry if this is a pathetic question, am still a little green!

Comment: Normalize.css (only) should handle things and is my preference.

Comment: James, please upvote or choose an answer if we answered your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should **not** use both Normalize and CSS Reset.

Normalize will make sure all your browsers display elements similarly without removing the "Default styling" from them. (like bullet points and paddings/margins for list items and lists)

I've used both for many years and I recommend Normalize as it's a less "agressive" method of cross-browser CSS "normalizing". A CSS reset will make all values 0 or none and you will often need to re-add the styling yourself.

You should also have a look in the Yahoo CSS reset ( http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/ ) which introduces the concept of "contextuality" in the reset; basically you can reset only some elements with the use of classes to limit your scope.

Answer (score 0):

Normalise.css and reset.css are different methods of achieving the same ends. I would therefor only bother including one or the other.

[What is the difference between Normalize.css and Reset CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css)

Seems to indicate normalise.css is preferable.