# I am looking for a CSS reset file for two year old or less browsers such as IE9 and above

Tags: html, css

I am using the following for reset to compensate for browser differences:

```
html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
del, dfn, em, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
b, u, i, center,
dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
fieldset, form, label, legend,
table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td,
article, aside, canvas, details, embed, 
figure, figcaption, footer, header, hgroup, 
menu, nav, output, ruby, section, summary,
time, mark, audio, video {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    font-size: 100%;
    font: inherit;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}
/* HTML5 display-role reset for older browsers */
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section {
    display: block;
}
body {
    line-height: 1;
}
ol, ul {
    list-style: none;
}
blockquote, q {
    quotes: none;
}
blockquote:before, blockquote:after,
q:before, q:after {
    content: '';
    content: none;
}
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
    border-spacing: 0;
}
```

The file I used is I think quite old. Does anyone have anything which is newer and which would be more appropriate for browsers less than a couple of years old for example IE9 and above? One of the main reasons I am asking this is that when I try to use the browser developer tools I am getting tired of seeing many entries from my reset file when I check CSS.

Comment: Not only does this reset stylesheet compensate for many "differences" that have never actually been differences, it also forgets quite a few differences that are! So yes, it's time to find a new one. For starters, can't you just, you know, not use this?

Comment: Surely any type of reset style sheet will clutter your dom inspector with many useless styles

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of the current (responsive) CSS frameworks use normalize.css like Twitter Bootstrap and Zurb Foundation

http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Please take a look here why you should use the normalize.css solution instead of reset.css
[What is the difference between Normalize.css and Reset CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css)

Answer (score 1):

You're making use of [Meyer's Reset](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) I think it's the best way to reset CSS properties. And you have to deal with those *many* entries anyhow if you want to use this or any other reset technique.