# Image overflows outside its container on certain actions (Firefox)

Tags: html, css, svelte

I'm using Firefox and I have noticed a simple problem that when I'm using a image slider sometimes images overflow out of their container to the top. But it's only happening when I'm using Firefox on Chrome everything works fine, any ideas?

[image]

I have tried adding overflow:hidden, but it didn't help in this case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this is only happening on certain browsers it might be because you haven't done a reset on your CSS values.

---

You might want to check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25626665/website-renders-differently-in-different-browsers) and see if you're facing the same issues. If so you could add a `reset.css` file to your project to fix the problems. For more information, please check out [CSS Reset](https://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: damn this one is a nice catch bro, thanks!:)

Comment: No worries, I've been there myself so I recognized the issue straight away. Good luck on the project!

Comment: one thing which I've noticed is that all my borders have now gone cuz of the reset.css :D I'm using tailwind and the basic fix of missing borders is using border-width or something like that, so I'll check on this

Comment: Hmm, tailwind does have it by default, I've tried removing border: 0; from reset.css and test if it would work without it, but then I'm getting the same old result, so I need to find a way how to use it with tailwind or just create a simple workaround https://tailwindcss.com/docs/preflight#border-styles-are-reset-globally

Comment: It's hard to tell what's going wrong there exactly as I cannot see your code. But the way `reset.css` works is that it just resets the defaults. If you specify your CSS-classes correctly, you should still be able to add a border to elements. It says so in the documentation you linked too!