# Unwanted top margin for h1 element

Tags: html, css

I am getting an unwanted top margin for an h1 element, not sure why. This is my html:

```
<body>
  <div class="content"> 
    <h1>Header</h1>
    <p>Paragraph 1.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 2.</p>
    <p>Paragraph 3.</p>
  </div>
</body>
```

This is my css:

```
body {
  background-color: yellow;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}

h1 {
  background-color: lime;
}

.content {
  background-color: pink;
  position: absolute;
  left: 0px;
  top: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
}
```

the result:

[image]

I was expecting the h1 element to be aligned with the top edge of the view.

If I remove the "position", "left" and "top" attributes from the css def, then the h1 element aligns to the top of the view as expected:

[image]

why is that happening? I'm using chrome.

Thanks

Comment: Erm, so add a `margin-top: 0;` for the H1. What's the big mystery here?

Comment: Yeah I'm trying to understand *why* it's happening.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add `margin:0;`:

```
h1 {
    margin:0;
    background-color: lime;
}
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/tb39am7s/

Answer (score 5):

For every element browser itself sets the default styles. That includes headings, which get some margin at top and bottom - you need to remove them by yourself in case you do not need them.

Unfortunally, those default styles differ from browser to browser, even if W3C gives [recommendation](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/sample.html), that is why developers try to [reset default styles](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/) or [normalize it](http://www.cssreset.com/scripts/normalize-css/) before they start adding their own. There is [difference between previous two](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css#answer-8357635).

Answer (score 2):

Remove top margin on your h1:

http://jsfiddle.net/austinthedeveloper/wwzxn8gx/

```
h1 {
    background-color: lime;
    margin-top: 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

h1 elements have a default margin. Adding `margin: 0;` to your h1 properties should clear up your margin issue. I believe that the margin is based on the element that contains it.

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="container">
<h1>HEADER</h1>
</div>

//style

div.container{
padding: 0;
}

h1{
margin-top: 0;
}
```

Also you coudl use normalize.css to reset the default values of some tags.
http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

Answer (score 0):

this happens because of default h1 "line height". you can add line-height property with any desired value like this:

```
h1{
    line-height: 1em;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

If you use `position: absolute` make sure to specify `position: relative` on the parent element it should be relative to (in your case this would be `<body>`) and see if this helps.

Answer (score -1):

You can do:

```
h1{
    margin:0
}
```