# Remove styling from semantic tags?

Tags: css, html

I'm using some semantic HTML5 elements in my foundation website, things like figure/blockquote etc.

I also use normalize.scss.

I was just wondering, whats the best way to remove any default styling with these tags? For example figure has extra margin.

Comment: Use a CSS reset that targets the elements you need if normalize.scss doesn't.

Comment: use one of css resets instead of normalize, which doesn't unstyle all elements - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css

Answer (score 2):

Popular normalize- and reset files already do quite a decent job when it comes to unifying the styles across browsers and platforms. "Removing" a style usually is not a good idea, because then the possibly different default values apply. What you probably rather want is set explicit minimalistic styles on certain elements after the normalize/reset styles unified them. If you don't use any overly exotic CSS features, you should get same style on all plattforms.

Comment: so perhaps just remove margin on my blockquotes in my sass rather than using a reset?

Comment: Why chose either one if you can have both? Just add your own styles after the reset.

Answer (score 1):

Normalize.scss adds default styles to elements. Your browser can also add default styles to elements. The answer probably differs based on which element you want to remove the styling from, but [Reset.css](http://cssreset.com/) strips away a lot of these default styles for you. If Reset does not remove default styling, then you will need to do so manually with your own CSS.