# Disable / overriding Joomla template CSS

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, templates, joomla, module

I am building a module in Bootstrap for Joomla. It has its own stylesheet, but the activated template (where I test it in) also uses Bootstrap and classes which adds some CSS to my module (tables, buttons, etc.).

I want my module to look the same in all different templates of Joomla. Is there a way of disabling the CSS of the template for my module so it just looks same on every template? Or do I have to declare every single line in CSS (with !important, because I think that's a lot of work?)

Answer (score 0):

The CSS is rendered within an HTML document, so you can't just "disable" it on a piece of the page (which is your module).

One possible approach is to render your module inside an `<iframe>` so it would be a separate document into the main HTML document. But I'm not sure if this would be good/recommended, so I would rather rewrite my CSS rules so they all are inherited from my module.

For example: if your module is the "Fancy Contact Module", you can use an wrapper `div` like `<div class="fancy-contact-module">` and write all your CSS rules like:

```
.fancy-contact-module p {
    color: green;
}
.fancy-contact-module a {
    text-decoration: none;
}
```

and so on.

You can also use your wrapper `div` to apply Reset CSS or Normalize CSS (or any other similar tool), so you won't need to override all CSS rules manually. You can see more about Reset and Normalize here: [What is the difference between Normalize.css and Reset CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css)