# Remove browser default styling <!DOCTYPE>

Tags: html, css, doctype

Is there a way or `<!DOCTYPE>` declaration such as `XHTML` or `HTML4`  that would remove the default CSS styling on elements?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Doctype is not used for styling. There are two prominent ways of removing all the styles and uniforming the default look.

1. normalize.css   https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/
2. reset.css http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

add these styles to your css before your stylesheet to uniform you layout to a certain degree, across different browsers. 
[What is the difference between Normalize.css and Reset CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css)

Comment: "add these styles to your css before your stylesheet and it removes all the styling" — No, they don't. They set different values for the styles. They can't remove them.

Comment: @YasinYaqoobi I loaded both in, but still default browser styles are being applied.

Comment: @JordanDavis post your code / screenshot so we can see exactly what's going on.  You can always use general selects like p,div,button, etc to override the styles manually, or you can just do * like quentin suggested.

Comment: You don't need to see the code its generalize to any and every element, can the browser render it with no properties, or at least override the defaults. The `DOCTYPE` would control the rendering of the properties depending on the version just let you know by the way

Answer (score 3):

I personally have been using the code below for all of my projects till date.

```
*{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Also here an article if you are looking for a complete reset of some kind http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/30194443)

Comment: @Joeri I agree. But I have no idea which styles does he want to be eliminated so I just posted a solution which is used by most developers. Thanks for your suggestions though. I will keep this in mind.

Comment: forgot colours outlines and all the other random junk the browser does by default too.

Answer (score -1):

No.

Elements have to have a default styling. It doesn't make sense for most properties to lack any value at all.

Take `display` for instance. If `display` wasn't set, how would the element render? The same way as if it was `display: none`? Then `none` would just be the default value.

If you don't like a default value for a property for a given element, then use a stylesheet to set a value you do like.

Comment: I understand that, but element namespaces like `table` are semantic but the default styling applied I don't like, instead of using `grid` or some other made up tag I'm wondering if there is a way to keep the namespaces the same.

Comment: @JordanDavis — "If you don't like a default value for a property for a given element, then use a stylesheet to set a value you do like." So set `table { something something something }`

Comment: There aren't *that* many elements, it's unlikely that you'd need to change every element (heck, it is unlikely that you'd need to change every element you actually use), and the universal selector (`*`) exists.

Comment: There are quite a few that need to be changed (table elements, form elements, progress, etc...) and yes I think the world knows about the `*` universal selector. Simply what I'm asking is an easy way to override/remove the default styling, and clearly you don't know a way, other than manually doing every one, am I right?

Comment: That's because the whole idea of someone being able to suggest a way to change the default values of every property on every element from "something you don't like" to "something you do like" requires that someone to have a huge amount of insight into your personal tastes. As I said in the answer, you can't have *no* styling at all, it has to look like something (or look like nothing, and even "nothing" is a style).

Comment: I'm not even talking about styling the elements to some personal taste, obviously that is the end goal, but reseting them to nothing with no properties is what I want, so I have a blank slate to be styled into my own personal taste, yes.

Comment: And as I have said, repeatedly, "a blank slate" doesn't really exist. Various people have their own ideas about what a blank slate is (and they tend not to agree with each other), Yasin linked to a couple in their answer, but when those ideas are implemented, it just comes down to writing a stylesheet that sets different values for the properties they want to change (which is what I said you have to do when I wrote the answer in the first place).

Comment: using a custom HTML tag is what I would call a blank slate like `<grid>`,`<row>`,`<item>`, where nothing is applied to it. But yes I think there is no way to do that, thats why I'm asking the question, if anyone knows a way.

Comment: You may be right, but lets see if anyone else answers and knows a way.

Comment: @JordanDavis — Making up invalid HTML doesn't give you a blank slate. Default styles are applied to the element. https://www.evernote.com/l/AAMOY2ksRLpGyI7xT-L7isLHZz4-cy2cmxE If you want to apply those styles to an element in a real HTML document, then you can … and you can use the universal selector if you want to apply them to every element at once.

Comment: Invalid HTML doesn't matter when you developing web application, there is no web-crawler that needs to index your page, and or can't even get past the login page.

Comment: No, just real people with real browsers, and real screen readers, and obscure browser plugins. That's not my point though.

Answer (score -3):

There are several ways to do that, depending on what you want to do.

You can override a style in case using `!important`, for example: 
     div{
        display: inline !important
     }

On buttons and inputs: 
     Input{ 
       -webkit-appearance: none; 
       -moz-appearance: none; 
       -ms-appearance: none /*not sure if it works on IE*/ 
      }

Comment: This doesn't override all the properties, even if you used the universal selector with `-webkit-appearance` there are defaults like `height:, margin:, etc..`

Comment: Sure, but you need to specify them, for example input{-webkit-appearance: none; height 20px !important; margin: 0px !important;}