# Absolute child inside a relative parent and then again, all of it inside in an absolute parent

Tags: html, css, css-position

I know, the title, sorry, but it makes sense. What I'm ultimately trying to achieve is create a container  "unrelated" to the body that still respects its size constraints where I can push some messages.

```
<div id="big-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
        <div id="child">
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In more detail, I'm trying to push `child`, which is an `absolute` div, inside the `#big-container` which is also `absolute`. To make my `child` actually snap to `big-container`, since they're both `absolute`, I decided to introduce a wrapper classes that's relative. The styling is as such:

```
#big-container {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 3; /* higher over everything else on the site */
}

.wrapper {
    position: relative;
}

#child {
    position: absolute;
}
```

Now, this works fine and dandy. Except...only on its own. See, thing is, I kinda wanna push these `child` to the container only so that I don't actually polute other divs/the normal flow. They are, after all, completely detached from the flow. But if I do this, anything that is under `#big-container` becomes unusable because, well, it's hidden by it. Let's see it in action:

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
}

#big-container {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
}

#child {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3> This is some content from the site!</h3>
  <p>...and some more!</p>
  <div id="big-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="child">
        I am the child! Try to select anything below me, see if it works.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

What am I missing here? I feel as if the markup itself is wrong. All I'm trying to do is be considerate of others and simply contain my messages to a single space.

Comment: I'm not clear on what behavior you want from the stuff outside the container, but does making the container sticky instead of absolute help at all?

Comment: @SydneyY Can you explain the choice for `sticky`? In my case, both make sense. How does it change the div's behavior? The stuff "outside" is basically the rest of the site. I want this container to be isolated.

Comment: Sticky is in the flow, whereas absolute is out of the flow. Do you want: on page load your container fills the screen, but the user can scroll down to see the content

Comment: @SydneyY That's correct! Let me read on `sticky` and see what I can cook up.

Comment: @SydneyY Doesn't solve my issue, my problem is that even if the container is `sticky`, I sitll can't get access to the things behind.

Comment: @DanielM - you probably need to tickle the `div`settings a bit. In the css.

Comment: @wahwahwah Well, sure, but that's why I'm here...how?

Comment: @DanielM is [it the same in all browsers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38361469/remove-browser-default-styling-doctype)? This might be a 'sticky' design-constraint issue... not a programming / css one

Answer (score 0):

Given your desired outcome, I would inject your container into the beginning of the body, use `vh` and `vw` to define height and width, and keep your container in the flow.

```
#big-container {
  margin:0;
  display:block;
  width:100vw;
  height:100vh;
}
```

```
let page = document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0]
let container = document.createElement('div')
container.setAttribute('id', 'big-container')
page.insertAdjacentElement('afterbegin', container)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Is it supposed to work this way?

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
}

#page {
  position: relative;
  z-index: 1;
}

#big-container {
  display: block;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
}

#child {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div id="page">
    <h3> This is some content from the site!</h3>
    <p>...and some more!</p>
  </div>
  <div id="big-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="child">
        I am the child! Try to select anything below me, it actually works.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

`#page` has a `z-index` of `1`. It's the most basic, lowest and most rudimentary value. There is no `z-index` for `#big-container` so that we don't force `#child` to any `z-index`, then we go ahead and set a higher `z-index` than `#page` for it.

I'm not sure if this is the best, but it works.

Answer (score 0):

All I changed is CSS of your `big-container`. And the bottom text is selectable now.

**The problem is:**

> Your `big-container` layer element is too large that covers the whole page, so your click only lies on this element

**What you need is:**

> only to create a higher level layer that display you push message

a) so you don't need an actual fully tiled element, but just a layer, so you don't need width and height 100%.

b) your `wrapper` requires a width of 100%, which means from the parent, so keep your parent 100% of width.

c) your message should be displayed, so just allow any overflow on your `big-container`

```css
body {
  width: 960px;
  height: 100%;
}

#big-container {
  display: block;
  height: 0;
  width: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  overflow: display;
}

.wrapper {
  display: block;
  width: 100%;
  height: inherit;
  position: relative;
  padding: 12px;
}

#child {
  background-color: red;
  border: 1px solid black;
  color: white;
  position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <h3> This is some content from the site!</h3>
  <p>...and some more!</p>
  <div id="big-container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <div id="child">
        I am the child! Try to select anything below me, see if it works.
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>
```

Comment: Hey, that's smart. I'll review and test how it interacts with the other things soon.