# Angular 2: How to correctly automatically import normalize.css

Tags: css, angular, typescript, normalize-css

I am a new Angular 2 user, and I have some problems with it.

Traditionally, we could use `<link rel="stylesheet" href="node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css" />` to import a css file, but I want to make Angular 2 to automatically import it using `import`.

I tried to use the same way when I used Material 2:

```html
// angular-cli-build.js

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'normalize-path/index.js',
    ]
  });
};
```

```html
// system-config.ts 

const map: any = {
  'normalize': 'vendor/normalize-path',
};

/** User packages configuration. */
const packages: any = {
  'normalize': {main: 'index.js'},
};
```

```html
// app.component.ts

import { normalize } from 'normalize-path';
```

The editor will complain:

> Cannot find module 'normalize-path'.

And the code won't compile. But I really have no idea what was wrong.

Comment: Doesn't make sense: normalize CSS must really be included as link tag, no need to overcomplicate.

Comment: Sorry, but I just curious about how to use normalize.css with  Angular....

Answer (score 62, accepted):

**Update for Angular 8**

1. Install the normalize.css library:

   ```
   npm install --save normalize.css
   ```
2. Import it in your styles.css

   ```
   @import '~normalize.css';
   ```

---

With the current (`1.0.0-beta.15`) version of angular-cli, the solution is quite easy:

1. `npm i normalize.css`
2. add `"../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"` in `apps[0].styles` in the config file `angular-cli.json`

*Note:* If using Angular 7, the config file is now `angular.json`, and the path to normalise.css in `apps[0].styles` should be `"../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css"`.

**Example:**

```
{
  "project": {
    "version": "1.0.0-beta.15",
    "name": "normalize.css-in-angular2"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": "assets",
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "mobile": false,
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environments": {
        "source": "environments/environment.ts",
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "addons": [],
  "packages": [],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "css",
    "prefixInterfaces": false
  }
}
```

Comment: note that the cli needs to be restarted for this to take effect

Comment: There is a better method of loading now. In the styles.css (or styles.scss if you use sass) add `@import '~normalize.css';` after doing the `npm install --save normalize.css`. The `~` denotes the import as a node module. The package.json of the 'normalize' module points to the correct .css file. I have tested this with Angular v5, latest CLI, with `ng serve --prod` and `--aot`

Comment: @Drenai What does the `--save` flag do, and what does the '~' mean? I did an npm install without `--save` but it doesn't work.

Comment: --save updates the package.json file to include the package. The ~ tells the scss compiler to look for the imported normalize.css in the node_modules folder

Answer (score 41):

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40071845/how-to-import-css-from-node-modules-in-webpack-angular2-app), all needed to do was:

1. Install the normalize.css library:

   ```
   npm install --save normalize.css
   ```
2. Import it in your styles.css

   ```
   @import '~normalize.css';
   ```

Comment: Worked like a charm, added into styles.scss

Comment: You can leave out the second `normalize.css`, just the first one is sufficient

Comment: If this appears to you as if it isn't working make sure you understand the scope of `normalize.css` and what it does and doesn't do. eg. I expected `ul` tag to be reset to 0 margin and while `reset.css` does this `normalize.css` does not. If you're new to normalize.css check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336

Comment: This will be deprecated on new versions of node-sass

Comment: @distante Thanks. Plans [are](https://sass-lang.com/blog/the-module-system-is-launched) to deprecate `@import` before October 2021 and remove it a year later. Annoyingly, this syntax doesn't seem to work with @use. The node-sass people are [planning to provide an importer](https://github.com/sass/node-sass/issues/2362#issuecomment-386846210) to allow importing from node_modules.

Answer (score 5):

The accepted response doesn't seem to be working on app. I needed to remove the `../` in the path name.

The *angular.json* styles bit should be something like this:

```
"styles": [
    "node_modules/normalize.css/normalize.css",
    "styles.css"
  ],
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// angular-cli-build.js

module.exports = function(defaults) {
  return new Angular2App(defaults, {
    vendorNpmFiles: [
      'systemjs/dist/system-polyfills.js',
      'systemjs/dist/system.src.js',
      'zone.js/dist/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'es6-shim/es6-shim.js',
      'reflect-metadata/**/*.+(ts|js|js.map)',
      'rxjs/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      '@angular2-material/**/*.+(js|js.map)',
      'normalize.css/normalize.css'
    ]
  });
};
```

and simple add the css link to index.html

```html
// index.html
<link href="vendor/normalize.css/normalize.css" rel="stylesheet">
```