# How to import CSS from node_modules in webpack angular2 app

Tags: css, angular, typescript, npm, webpack

Let's say that we start with the following starter pack:
https://github.com/angularclass/angular2-webpack-starter

After `npm install` and `npm run start` everything works fine.

I want to add an external css module, for example bootstrap 4's css (and only the css). (I know that bootstrap has a bootstrap-loader, but now I'm asking for general solution, so please think about bootstrap 4 here as it could be any other css module that is available via npm).

I install bootstrap via npm: `npm install bootstrap@4.0.0-alpha.4 --save`

First I thought that it is enough to add `import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` to the vendor.browser.ts file.

But it isn't.

What should I do to have a proper solution?

Solutions I'm NOT asking for:

1. "Copy the external css module to the assets folder, and use it from there"

   - I'm looking for a solution that works together with npm package.
2. "Use bootstrap-loader for webpack"

   - As I described above, I'm looking for a general solution, bootstrap is only an example here.
3. "Use another stack"

   - I'm looking for a solution in the exact starter pack that I've mentioned above.

Comment: Are you getting any error?

Comment: This is officially the best SO thread I've ever been on. Stellar question and two equally stellar answers. Thanks all.

Answer (score 82, accepted):

You won't be able to import any css to your **vendors** file using that stack, without making some changes.

Why? Well because this line:

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

It's only importing your css as string, when in reality what you want is your vendor css in a style tag. If you check `config/webpack.commons.js` you will find this rule:

```
 {
   test: /\.css$/,
   loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader']
 },
```

This rule allows your components to import the css files, basically this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.css' // this why you import css as string
  ],
```

In the AppComponent there's no encapsulation, because of this line `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,` which means any css rules will be applied globally to your app. So you can import the bootstrap styles in your app component:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
  styleUrls: [
    './app.component.css',
    '../../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css'
  ],
```

But if you insist in importing to your `vendor.ts` then you will need to install a new loader, `npm i style-loader --save-dev` this will allow webpack to inject css to your page. Then you need to create a specific rule, on your webpack.common.js and change the existing one:

```
 { //this rule will only be used for any vendors
   test: /\.css$/,
   loaders: ['style-loader', 'css-loader'],
   include: [/node_modules/]
 },
 {
   test: /\.css$/,
   loaders: ['to-string-loader', 'css-loader'],
   exclude: [/node_modules/] //add this line so we ignore css coming from node_modules
 },
```

The firs rule will be only applied when you try to import css, from any package inside `node_modules` the second rule will be applied to any css that you import from outside the `node_modules`

Comment: Thanks dude, this is a kind of perfect answer I was looking for. Both solution works well. One thing that I didn't know is that it's possible to target node_modules from styleUrls. Is it also a preferred thing to do?

Comment: There's no right or wrong, either them are valid, but if in the future you plan on having your vendor.css in a separated file then, the last option is better.

Comment: note that the angular2-webpack-starter has already style-loader in its package.json (which means that no additional npm install is needed to use it in this example)

Comment: @Burnee true, but it's bot being used anywhere, so they might remove it in the future. So will leave in the answer, just in case, for future readers.

Comment: How to make my Angular app treat installed library's import `@import "~dist/3rd_party_lib/blabla.css` as `node_modules/dist/3rd_party_lib/blabla.css`, not as `https://localhost:4200/~/dist/3rd_party_lib/blabla.css`?

Comment: This is the best solution i found. Moreover, you can import you leaflet css file under any scss or css file like:
`@import "leaflet/dist/leaflet.css";`
while compiling, angular will import directy from `node_modules` folder

Answer (score 109):

It is possible by using `@import '~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';` on the styles.css file. (Note the **~**)

Edit: How it works - The '~' is an alias set on the webpack config pointing to the assets folder... simple as that..

Edit 2: Example on how to configure webpack with the '~' alias...
this should go on the webpack config file (usually `webpack.config.js`)...

```js
// look for the "resolve" property and add the following...
// you might need to require the asset like '~/bootsrap/...'
resolve: {
  alias: {
    '~': path.resolve('./node_modules')
  }
}
```

Comment: This worked for me and I really like the idea of keeping my css files contained so I didnt want to use the ViewEncapsulation.none deal. But how does this work?

Comment: As far as I know is something on the compiler, but since I'm not an expert, I'll leave this to someone who knows better to explain how it works...

Comment: I tried this but get an error: GET http://localhost:55490/~bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css 404 (Not Found)

Comment: For those who want to understand how does this work, here is a nice read https://blog.angularindepth.com/this-is-how-angular-cli-webpack-delivers-your-css-styles-to-the-client-d4adf15c4975

Comment: This did not used to work in Angular 6 but it works for Angular 7. I can't see anything in the changelog that explains why, though. Does anybody know?

Comment: @bubble as I explained in the edit, it only works because it's configured in webpack. Probabbly it was not correctly set up on your angular 6 project. I'll edit my answer again with some example...

Comment: This does not work angular 13

Answer (score 22):

So here is a way to import various `CSS` files using the `angular-cli` which I find the most convenient.

Basically, you can refer to the `CSS` files (order is important if you will be overriding them) in the config and `angular-cli` will take care of the rest. For instance, you might want to include a couple of styles from node-modules, which can be done as follows:

```
"styles": [
    "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
    "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
    "styles.css"
  ]
```

A sample full-config might look like this:

**.angular-cli.json**

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
    "name": "my-angular-app"
  },
  "apps": [
    {
      "root": "src",
      "outDir": "dist",
      "assets": [
        "assets",
        "favicon.ico"
      ],
      "index": "index.html",
      "main": "main.ts",
      "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
      "test": "test.ts",
      "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
      "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
      "prefix": "app",
      "styles": [
        "../node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
        "../node_modules/primeng/resources/primeng.min.css",
        "styles.css"
      ],
      "scripts": [],
      "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
      "environments": {
        "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
        "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
      }
    }
  ],
  "e2e": {
    "protractor": {
      "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "lint": [
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    },
    {
      "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
      "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
    }
  ],
  "test": {
    "karma": {
      "config": "./karma.conf.js"
    }
  },
  "defaults": {
    "styleExt": "scss",
    "component": {}
  }
}
```