# What is normalized css?

Tags: html, css

My question is very basic but i didn't find its answer on stack overflow. I like to know how to use normalized.css in "CSS" files. I know that normalized.css help you to make CSS files that can be used in any browser.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css

Comment: [normalized.css](https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=normalized.css)

Comment: You can find out the answer very easily using google.

Comment: You need to add references. The file "normalized.css" could exist in many different contexts. Your question will be downvoted because of this and many other reasons.

Comment: Just include the `normalize.css` as the very first css file on your page. Then proceed as you're used to.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Normalize.css is an open source .css file that Nicolas Gallagher made on GitHub: https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/

It allows you to apply a "Reset" to your code in order to let most modern browsers use your CSS. To use it, you need to link to it in your HTML like you would any other CSS, but **make sure** it's above the main stylesheet so that the "Reset" is applied before your own styles.

http://adamkaplan.me/css-workshop/#normalize

Comment: Nice to see that even simple questions sometimes get short, helpful and concise answers.

Answer (score 3):

[normalized.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) like yahoo's [reset.css](http://yuilibrary.com/yui/docs/cssreset/) and a few others ([HTML 5 doctor reset](http://html5doctor.com/html-5-reset-stylesheet/), [Vanilla unreset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/vanilla-css-un-reset/), [Universal * reset](http://cssreset.com/scripts/universal-selector-css-reset/)) aim to make all/most browsers by default look as similar as possible so that you can start from there and then only add the CSS you need that deviates from that point.

Answer (score 1):

Every browser have some predefined css for different HTML tags and css is usually different for different browsers. Like some default padding or margin on div or body. Normalize css just reset everything. So the css you added will show exact same effects in every browser.