# Child div doesn't fit to parent div can't be resolve with font-size:0?

Tags: html, css

```html
  <div class="order_ulasan_wrapper_1" style="width:100%; border:solid 1px #ccc; margin-top:15px; font-size:0;">
       <div class="title" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;/* display: block; */width: 100%;">
        <div class="title_1" style="width: 70%;display:inline-block;border-right:solid 1px #ccc;font-size:12px;">
         left box
        </div>

        <div class="title_2" style="width:30%; display:inline-block; font-size:12px;">
         right-box
        </div>
       </div>
    </div>
```

I have a parent div with width:100% and i want to divide it into two child div with width:70% and width:30% then make it inline. But why my right goes down?

Comment: @DeepakYadav font-size:0; doesn't work sir

Comment: my mistake, i thought you already have added any `reset` or `normalizer`. But it wasn't. The issue is due to `box-sizing`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a `CSS Reset` or set a proper `box-sizing` property.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="order_ulasan_wrapper_1" style="width:100%; border:solid 1px #ccc; margin-top:15px; font-size:0;">
  <div class="title" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;/* display: block; */width: 100%;">
    <div class="title_1" style="width: 70%;display:inline-block;border-right:solid 1px #ccc;font-size:12px;">
      left box
    </div>

    <div class="title_2" style="width:30%; display:inline-block; font-size:12px;">
      right-box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

> Read more about `Normalize` and `CSS-reset`

[Stack overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css)

Answer (score 1):

The issue is `border-right` in class `.title_1` if you remove that it align both divs properly and if you want to keep that then use `box-sizing:border-box` or else `reduce` the `width` of `.title_1`

Remove **border-right**

```html
<div class="order_ulasan_wrapper_1" style="width:100%; border:solid 1px #ccc; margin-top:15px; font-size:0;">
  <div class="title" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;/* display: block; */width: 100%;">
    <div class="title_1" style="width: 70%;display:inline-block; #ccc;font-size:12px;">
      left box
    </div>

    <div class="title_2" style="width:30%; display:inline-block; font-size:12px;">
      right-box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Reduce width**

```html
<div class="order_ulasan_wrapper_1" style="width:100%; border:solid 1px #ccc; margin-top:15px; font-size:0;">
  <div class="title" style="border-bottom:solid 1px #ccc;/* display: block; */width: 100%;">
    <div class="title_1" style="width: 68%;display:inline-block;border-right:solid 1px; #ccc;font-size:12px;">
      left box
    </div>

    <div class="title_2" style="width:30%; display:inline-block; font-size:12px;">
      right-box
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```