# When would one use Reset CSS over Normalize.css?

Tags: css, normalize-css

I have read this Stack Overflow question on differences between [Normalize.css vs Reset CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css), but it doesn't mention when which approach should be used. To me, it seems like normalize.css has way more advantages over Reset CSS.

I can't think of a situation where I would use Reset CSS over normalize.css. Does anyone know of any reason or use case where using Reset CSS is more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

A reset should be more durable when browsers change their default styles. Useful if you're going for complete control over the look

And if you're going for a minimalist style, a reset might be closer to your final style than normalize is

But I mostly agree: if you want a non-ugly website with less effort (and nicer debugging), normalize is a better starting point