# Is it worth using *{margin:0; padding:0;} as resetting purpose

Tags: html, css

I am beginner at HTML and CSS and faced the confusion about if it is ok to use `*{margin:0; padding:0;}` or it really affects performance of the web page. I have already read the other article about it in the platform but some responders say that it affects and some say does not. Please would you give concrete answer if *{margin:0; padding:0;} affects the performance or not. I really need your help.

Comment: *I have already read the other article about it in the platform but some responders say that it affects and some say does not. I do not to whom to believe.* What makes any additional answers you get here more believable? ;)

Comment: here is the link differences between reset and normalize. it will help you to know why most of website is using normalize or reboot instead of reseting.
[link here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css)

Comment: why not set up some benchmark tests and D.I.Y it? :

Comment: @lurker, Hey man, yes I know but I meant to say each tries to say their own opinions concerning this issue and I just wanted to get concrete answer with proof if it affects or not. That's it.

Comment: It is "Ok" about performances, as it won't have any important impact. But it is not a good practice.

Comment: that's really opinionated, what you get from the reset is browser consistency - all browsers have the same default values. What you trade off is having a little more CSS to parse, that little more CSS shouldn't make a sensible effect on the performance of the page render though

Comment: @QuentinVeron, hey Quentin thank you for your reply, ok if it does not affect the performance then is it ok to use it in real projects, if not should I use normalize.css? if yes then it does not contain padding:0; then what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

If you reset all elements maybe performance is not big a deal here or difference for performance is not countable, specially nowadays browsers are faster.

> By reseting  basically you have to write style for every elements and
>   on the other hand you have to think about cross browser consistency
>   and think about bugs like `SVG` overflow in IE9, `font-size` rendering
>   for `pre` element......etc.

- Basically if you like built in style and care about css file size then use normalize css.
- If you don't like built in styles like default margin or padding for `H1-H6,P`..etc and care more about cross browser consistency then use reset css.