# Using grid for layout, have unwanted padding left of first picture

Tags: css, css-grid

There is unwanted padding on the left of my first img, with this layout. The only other question I found like this, suggested putting margin:0, but I already have that at the top of my css. This specific part of my code is part of a media query if that is relevant.
(also for the #intro snippet, for me on here it shows some of them indented differently from each other, but they are indented right on dreamweaver, but editing doesnt seem to fix them on here sorry)

```css
 #intro{
     display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     grid-template-areas: 
  "a c b";
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
 }

 #intro img{
  padding-bottom: 30px;
 }

 #intro img:first-of-type{
  grid-area: a;
 }

 #intro img:last-of-type {
  grid-area: b;
 }

 #intro p{
  grid-area: c;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding:30px 0px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  
  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="c 1">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="c 2">

  <p>By popular demand...</p>
 
  
 </section>
```

Comment: I already have a CSS reset in the code.

Answer (score 1):

```
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 16px;
}

*, *:before, *:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

body, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, ol, ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
}

ol, ul {
  list-style: none;
}

img {
 max-width: 100%;
 height: auto;
}
```

Use **Minimal CSS Reset** before your style.

[normalize.css](https://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/)

[Check this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css)

Answer (score 0):

Add

```
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
```

```css
body {
    margin: 0px;
}
#intro{
     display:grid;
  grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr 1fr;
     grid-template-areas: 
  "a c b";
  grid-column-gap: 40px;
  grid-template-rows: auto;
 }

 #intro img{
  padding-bottom: 30px;
 }

 #intro img:first-of-type{
  grid-area: a;
 }

 #intro img:last-of-type {
  grid-area: b;
 }

 #intro p{
  grid-area: c;
  font-size: 25px;
  padding:30px 0px;
  line-height: 40px;
  text-align: center;
 }
```

```html
<section id="intro">
  
  
  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="c 1">

  <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/150/" alt="c 2">

  <p>By popular demand...</p>
 
  
 </section>
```