# Im getting whitespace that borders my webpage on all 4 sides

Tags: html, css

I have tried setting the padding and margins to 0. I have tried making the overflow-x and overflow-y values hidden. I have tried to set the width to 100% or 100vw. I don't really know what else to do, but i still have this whitespace.

here is the css attached to my header:

```
header{
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579128860537-64fcd61568bf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2559&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: serif;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
}
```

Comment: Have you used dev tools on your browser to inspect it? If not, take a look at [how to sue dev tools](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools). It looks like you are missing the thing actually affecting the page. That is just the header. It could be on the main element or somewhere else. Dev tools will help you find it easily. Nutshell is right click on the whitespace and inspect... look at the CSS rules to find the culprit.

Answer (score 1):

Don't forget to zero out the `margin` on the `body`.

```css
header{
  text-align: center;
  background: url("https://images.unsplash.com/photo-1579128860537-64fcd61568bf?ixlib=rb-1.2.1&ixid=eyJhcHBfaWQiOjEyMDd9&auto=format&fit=crop&w=2559&q=80");
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  color:white;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: serif;
  height:100vh;
  margin: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
  padding: 0px 0px 0px 0px;
} 

body { margin: 0; }
```

```html
<header></header>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9avmdy5s/)

Answer (score 1):

Your `header` style is fine, it is the `margin` of your `body` that you need to set to `0`. Simply add this style to your css file:

```
body {
  margin: 0;
}
```

Edit:

Another solution is to add [normalize.css](http://necolas.github.io/normalize.css/) to your project: its a modern, HTML5-ready alternative to CSS resets.
You can read more about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css).

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/beavis/k21sdh9v/)

Answer (score 0):

The `margin` on the `body` defaults to `8px`. You just need to set this value to `0`.

```
body {
    margin: 0;
}
```