# How to efficiently remove user-agent stylings applied to my anchor tags

Tags: html, css

I'm using Chrome and am styling `a` (anchor) tags.

```css
a {
  all: unset;
}
```

I believe `all: unset` sets all properties applied to `a` either to be initial or `inherit` if a property's naturally inheritable (e.g. `color`).

1. `a {all: unset}` does make `text-decoration: underline` turn into `text-decoration: none`. However, it doesn't 'unset' `color: -webkit-link` (which makes text purple). My solution: `a {color: unset}`.

Why am I forced to do this additional solution? And is there a more effective solution other than repeating `a {property: unset}` every-time a property not captured by `all: unset` is discovered?

2. Here's a second example: If I want to make a `a` `box-sizing: border-box`,  `* {box-sizing: border-box}` won't work. `a {box-sizing: border-box}` does. I don't know why this is.

---

Here's something that might be useful. Here's what Chrome Inspector shows me of `a`.

```css
a:-webkit-any-link {
    color: -webkit-link;
    cursor: pointer;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

Although it just adds more confusion to me because I thought my solutions (using the `a` selector) wouldn't 'capture' a pseudo-class (`a:-webkit-any-link`)

---

P.S.

The ultimate goal behind this question (if this goal is reasonable) is to stop these user-agent stylings (like `color` ) from being applied to my `a` tags (on Chrome & any other browser).

Comment: Rather than "disable", you could try to use `normalize.css` or `reset.css`. Both libraries would help you achieve a more consistent default style. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6887336/what-is-the-difference-between-normalize-css-and-reset-css

Comment: I don't want to get into css rests now because it's just a portfolio piece i'm making. What'd be useful is i) some insight as to what's going on & ii) any other significant, non-obvious user-agent settings being applied to `a` (or any other element). (Imo, `color` & `box-size` were significant).

Comment: iii) given the CSS properties I've mentioned, how would I make it so that they don't run the risk of getting overwritten by a different browser's user-agent stylings?

Answer (score 1):

This should be all you need:

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
  text-decoration: none;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">yourLink</a>
```

Comment: Sure + my point #2 still stands. Im also left with the question: why doesn’t the universal selector just work?